# Can a conversion from double to int be written in portable C

Tags: c, floating-point, standards

I need to write function like `double_to_int(double val, int *err)` which
would covert double val to integer when it's possible; otherwise report an error (NAN/INFs/OUT_OF_RANGE).

so pseudo code implementation would look like:

```
if isnan(val):
    err = ERR_NAN
    return 0
if val < MAX_INT:
    err = ERR_MINUS_INF
    return MIN_INT
if ...
return (int)val
```

There are at least two similar questions on SO:
in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544394/c-floating-point-to-integer-type-conversions/2545218) answer it's solved in enough clean way, though it's C++ solution - in C we do not have portable digits for signed int.
In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17822304/4625005) answer, it's explained why we cannot just check `(val > INT_MAX || val < INT_MIN)`.

So the only possible clean way i see is to use floating point environment, but it's stated as implementation-defined feature.

So my question: **is there any way to implement `double_to_int` function in cross-platform way (basing only on C standard, even not considering 
target platforms to support IEEE-754).?**

Comment: "Please read before marking as duplicate." should go on comment section

Comment: I wonder if `frexp` is any help.

Comment: I really feel like your question is answer by [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905246/how-to-check-if-float-can-be-exactly-represented-as-an-integer/17822304#17822304) you linked in your question, thus make your question a duplicate.

Comment: You really should explain why the answer shown by Stargateur does not answer your question.

Comment: I feel that all the "close duplicates" fail over to a particular implementation at some point in their answers. I strongly believe that it's not possible to do this; my answer is little more than an invitation to peer review.

Comment: Should `if val < MAX_INT:` be `if val < MIN_INT:`?

Comment: @Barmar: Probably but it doesn't matter really: that method is not portable.

Comment: @Bathsheba "fail over to a particular implementation" => "even not considering target platforms to support IEEE-75", but so your answer must be correct, it's impossible. Finally, wanting to convert a floating number to an integer is already a problem itself.

Comment: @Stargateur; Absolutely!

Comment: The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544394/c-floating-point-to-integer-type-conversions/2545218) you point to (but call an answer—your link is to the question, not an answer) does not contain the string “digits10”, so I do not see why the lack of a digits10 would preclude using that answer. (Other C++ versus C issues might, but you seem to have mistaken something.)

Comment: Why am I the only upvoter? I don't think this is obvious. Seems like a "go-via-the-string-route" solution is emerging.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, yes, that's a mistake (also misunderstood meaning of digits) - though in this case the code in answer just wrong.

Comment: In the question you link to, you could take the `uint64_t double_to_uint64 (double x)` and modify it for signed (which is easy: check the sign, and use the right arguments to ldexp)

Comment: @M.M, 1. might be relevant for intN_t but not for int. 2. Nothing prevents DBL_MANT_DIG to be less then 32 - 1.

Comment: Can someone explain why standard C `lrint()` can't be used?

Comment: @Lundin The lrint and llrint functions round their argument to the nearest integer value, rounding according to the current rounding direction. If the rounded value is outside the range of the return type, the numeric result is unspecified. A range error *may* occur if the magnitude of x is too large.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I have completely revised my answer.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer has been edited with a completely new approach.]

This approach uses the definition of floating-point formats in the C standard—as a signed base-*b* numeral multiplied by a power of *b*. Knowing the number of digits in the significand (provided by `DBL_MANT_DIG`) and the exponent limit (provided by `DBL_MAX_EXP`) allows us to prepare exact `double` values as end points.

I believe it will work in all conforming C implementations subject to the modest additional requirements stated in the initial comment.

```
/*  This code demonstrates safe conversion of double to int in which the
    input double is converted to int if and only if it is in the supported
    domain for such conversions (the open interval (INT_MIN-1, INT_MAX+1)).
    If the input is not in range, an error is indicated (by way of an
    auxiliary argument) and no conversion is performed, so all behavior is
    defined.

    There are a few requirements not fully covered by the C standard.  They
    should be uncontroversial and supported by all reasonable C implementations:

        Conversion of an int that is representable in double produces the
        exact value.

        The following operations are exact in floating-point:

            Dividing by the radix of the floating-point format, within its
            range.

            Multiplying by +1 or -1.

            Adding or subtracting two values whose sum or difference is
            representable.

        FLT_RADIX is representable in int.

        DBL_MIN_EXP is not greater than -DBL_MANT_DIG.  (The code can be
        modified to eliminate this requirement.)

    Deviations from the requested routine include:

        This code names the routine DoubleToInt instead of double_to_int.

        The only error indicated is ERANGE.  Code to distinguish the error more
        finely, such as providing separate values for NaNs, infinities, and
        out-of-range finite values, could easily be added.
*/


#include <float.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>


/*  These values will be initialized to the greatest double value not greater
    than INT_MAX+1 and the least double value not less than INT_MIN-1.
*/
static double UpperBound, LowerBound;


/*  Return the double of the same sign of x that has the greatest magnitude
    less than x+s, where s is -1 or +1 according to whether x is negative or
    positive.
*/
static double BiggestDouble(int x)
{
    /*  All references to "digits" in this routine refer to digits in base
        FLT_RADIX.  For example, in base 3, 77 would have four digits (2212).

        In this routine, "bigger" and "smaller" refer to magnitude.  (3 is
        greater than -4, but -4 is bigger than 3.)
    */

    //  Determine the sign.
    int s = 0 < x ? +1 : -1;

    //  Count how many digits x has.
    int digits = 0;
    for (int t = x; t; ++digits)
        t /= FLT_RADIX;

    /*  If the double type cannot represent finite numbers this big, return the
        biggest finite number it can hold, with the desired sign.
    */
    if (DBL_MAX_EXP < digits)
        return s*DBL_MAX;

    //  Determine whether x is exactly representable in double.
    if (DBL_MANT_DIG < digits)
    {
        /*  x is not representable, so we will return the next lower
            representable value by removing just as many low digits as
            necessary.  Note that x+s might be representable, but we want to
            return the biggest double less than it, which is also the biggest
            double less than x.
        */

        /*  Figure out how many digits we have to remove to leave at most
            DBL_MANT_DIG digits.
        */
        digits = digits - DBL_MANT_DIG;

        //  Calculate FLT_RADIX to the power of digits.
        int t = 1;
        while (digits--) t *= FLT_RADIX;

        return x / t * t;
    }
    else
    {
        /*  x is representable.  To return the biggest double smaller than
            x+s, we will fill the remaining digits with FLT_RADIX-1.
        */

        //  Figure out how many additional digits double can hold.
        digits = DBL_MANT_DIG - digits;

        /*  Put a 1 in the lowest available digit, then subtract from 1 to set
            each digit to FLT_RADIX-1.  (For example, 1 - .001 = .999.)
        */
        double t = 1;
        while (digits--) t /= FLT_RADIX;
        t = 1-t;

        //  Return the biggest double smaller than x+s.
        return x + s*t;
    }
}


/*  Set up supporting data for DoubleToInt.  This should be called once prior
    to any call to DoubleToInt.
*/
static void InitializeDoubleToInt(void)
{
    UpperBound = BiggestDouble(INT_MAX);
    LowerBound = BiggestDouble(INT_MIN);
}


/*  Perform the conversion.  If the conversion is possible, return the
    converted value and set *error to zero.  Otherwise, return zero and set
    *error to ERANGE.
*/
static int DoubleToInt(double x, int *error)
{
    if (LowerBound <= x && x <= UpperBound)
    {
        *error = 0;
        return x;
    }
    else
    {
        *error = ERANGE;
        return 0;
    }
}


#include <string.h>


static void Test(double x)
{
    int error, y;
    y = DoubleToInt(x, &error);
    printf("%.99g -> %d, %s.\n", x, y, error ? strerror(error) : "No error");
}


#include <math.h>


int main(void)
{
    InitializeDoubleToInt();
    printf("UpperBound = %.99g\n", UpperBound);
    printf("LowerBound = %.99g\n", LowerBound);

    Test(0);
    Test(0x1p31);
    Test(nexttoward(0x1p31, 0));
    Test(-0x1p31-1);
    Test(nexttoward(-0x1p31-1, 0));
}
```

Comment: @NominalAnimal: An interesting idea, I will think about whether converting to `unsigned int` gives us some leeway. However, the conversion caused by a cast from `double` to `unsigned int` is not necessarily modulo. Per C 2011 (N1570) 6.3.1.4 note 61, “The remaindering operation performed when a value of integer type is converted to unsigned type need not be performed when a value of real floating type is converted to unsigned type. Thus, the range of portable real floating values is (−1, U*type*_MAX+1).”

Comment: `limits.h` defines `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN`.

Comment: @BobJarvis: What is your point? We do not have any issue with obtaining `INT_MAX` or `INT_MIN` in `int`. The problem is we do not know they can be converted to `double` without error, but we need to find the greatest `double` that is less than `INT_MAX`+1. So we need to find some way to evade or correct for the rounding errors that may occur during conversion.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I rewrote my answer to use `floor(max_double_to_int) == (double)INT_MAX` and `ceil(min_double_to_int) == (double)INT_MIN` in the `nextafter()` loops, plus handling for the odd case when `DBL_MAX <= INT_MAX` or `-DBL_MAX >= INT_MIN` via `strtod()`.

Comment: The request was for "portable C", which raises the question of "Which one?"  AFAIK, `nexttoward(..)` first appeared in C99; it's not in ANSI C. Can `nexttoward(..)` be written in ANSI C?

Comment: @BobJacobsen As far as I can see, the question mentions *"cross-platform way (basing only on C standard, even not considering target platforms to support IEEE-754)"*. I doubt the OP is talking about C89, usually the *latest* standard (C11, now) is considered, but you can ask them for clarifications.

Comment: Magic number `0x1p31-1` in the test depends on 32-bit `int`.  With wide `int`, `(double)INT_MIN-1` is also problematic.  Perhaps a re-write of calls to `Test()` to show when the error value changes?  I also tried code, with adjustments for `long long`, and saw no troubles,

Comment: @chux: Yes, the tests are little more than demonstrative, as I did not put any effort into covering a variety of cases that could occur in different C implementations.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to "*Can* a conversation from double to int be written in portable C" is clearly "*yes*".

For example, you could sprintf the floating value to a string, do string-based inspection (i.e. by string-based comparison to max and min values you also sprintf’d), validation, rounding, etc and then sscanf the known-valid string for the final value.

In effect, you’d be moving toward an intermediate representation that’s (a) portable and (b) convenient. C strings are fine at portability, but not so convenient. If you can use external libraries, there are several that are convenient, but whose portability should be confirmed.

For example (which omits rounding):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

int convert(double inVal) {
    // basic range check - does anybody have an integer format with more than 300 bits?
    if (fabs(inVal) > 1.0E100) {
        printf("well out of range");
        return 1;
    }

    // load string buffer with input
    char buf[110];
    sprintf(buf, "%0105.0f", inVal);

    // do range check on strings
    if (inVal < 0) {
        char minVal[110];
        sprintf(minVal, "%0105d", INT_MIN);
        if (strcmp(buf, minVal) > 0) {
            printf("too small input: %f\n", inVal);
            return -1;  // needs better error signify
        }
    } else {
        char maxVal[110];
        sprintf(maxVal, "%0105d", INT_MAX);
        if (strcmp(maxVal, buf) < 0) {
            printf("too large input: %f\n", inVal);
            return -1;  // needs better error signify
        }
    }

    // do final conversion
    int result;
    sscanf(buf, "%d", &result);

    printf("input: %f result: %d\n", inVal, result);  // diagnostic

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    // test values    
    convert( 0.);
    convert( -123.5);
    convert( 123.5);

    convert( ((double)INT_MIN)-1);
    convert( ((double)INT_MIN));
    convert( ((double)INT_MIN)+1);
    convert( 2.0*((double)INT_MIN));
    convert( ((double)INT_MIN)/2);

    convert( ((double)INT_MAX)-1);
    convert( ((double)INT_MAX));
    convert( ((double)INT_MAX)+1);
    convert( 2.0*((double)INT_MAX));
    convert( ((double)INT_MAX)/2);

    return 0;
}
```

Which produces the expected conversions (see test cases at end above):

```
% gcc test.c ; ./a.out
input: 0.000000 result: 0
input: -123.500000 result: -124
input: 123.500000 result: 124
too small input: -2147483649.000000
input: -2147483648.000000 result: -2147483648
input: -2147483647.000000 result: -2147483647
too small input: -4294967296.000000
input: -1073741824.000000 result: -1073741824
input: 2147483646.000000 result: 2147483646
input: 2147483647.000000 result: 2147483647
too large input: 2147483648.000000
too large input: 4294967294.000000
input: 1073741823.500000 result: 1073741824
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can a conversion from `double` to `int` be written in portable C (?)
>
> is there any way to implement double_to_int function in cross-platform way (basing only on C standard, even not considering target platforms to support IEEE-754).?

```
int double_to_int(double val, int *err)
```

Detail: `(int)val` truncates the fractional portion, so the range of convertible `val` using `(int)val` is *mathematically*:
`INT_MIN - 0.9999... ≤ val ≤ INT_MAX + 0.9999...` or
`INT_MIN - 1         < val < INT_MAX + 1`.

---

Yes a cross-platform way, by using exact floating-point math and constants, code can test for conversion success.

`2.0*(INT_MAX/2+1)` is certainly exactly converted to a FP constant.

`val - INT_MIN > -1.0` is akin to `val > INT_MIN - 1.0` but does not suffer imprecision (with the common 2's complement machines) possible with `INT_MIN - 1.0`.  Recall that the integer type may have greater precision than `double`.  Consider a 64-bit `int` and `INT_MIN - 1.0` not exactly representable as a `double`.

Code does not use `(double)INT_MAX` which also may be imprecise.

---

To copy [myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51310061/2410359):

```
#include <limits.h>
#define DBL_INT_MAXP1 (2.0*(INT_MAX/2+1)) 
#define DBL_INT_MINM1 (2.0*(INT_MIN/2-1)) 

int double_to_int(double val, int *err) {
  if (val < DBL_INT_MAXP1) {
    #if -INT_MAX == INT_MIN
    // rare non-2's complement machine 
    if (val > DBL_INT_MINM1) {
      *err = OK;
      return (int) val;
    }
    #else
    if (val - INT_MIN > -1.0) {
      *err = OK;
      return (int) val;
    }
    #endif 
    // Underflow
    *err = ERR_MINUS_INF;
    return INT_MIN;
  }
  if (x > 0) {
    // Overflow
    *err = ERR_PLUS_INF;
    return INT_MAX;
  }
  // NaN;
  *err = ERR_NAN;
  return 0;
}
```

Corner weakness: `FLT == 10` and the integer type > 34 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might work:

```
#define BYTES_TO_BITS(x)    (x*8)

void numToIntnt(double num, int *output) {
    const int upperLimit = ldexp(1.0, (BYTES_TO_BITS(sizeof(int))-1))-1;
    const int lowerLimit = (-1)*ldexp(1.0, (BYTES_TO_BITS(sizeof(int))-1));

    /*
     * or a faster approach if the rounding is acceptable:
     * const int upperLimit = ~(1<<(BYTES_TO_BITS(sizeof(int))-1));
     * const int lowerLimit = (1<<(BYTES_TO_BITS(sizeof(int))-1));
     */

    if(num > upperLimit) {
        /* report invalid conversion */
    } else if (num < lowerLimit) {
        /* report invalid conversion */
    } else {
        *output = (int)num;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would that return a value of zero?

Comment: @AndrewHenle IMO the goal is to achieve a proper conversion, instead of an error log, which I have tried to simplify it (actually both errors are reporting the same value, in a variable in which any value is expected). Anyway, I have edited the code in order to make it clearer.

Comment: The calculation of `upperLimit` attempts to calculate 2^width-1, where width is the number of bits in an `int`. Even if some of those bits are padding bits, so they do not contribute to the available values, subtracting 1 is a problem. C does not specify what happens if the result is not exactly representable in floating-point. It might round up or down. Then you do not know whether you should use `val < upperLimit` or `val <= upperLimit`.

Comment: Testing `val > upperLimit` will report false for a NaN, as will the other comparison, so this code will fall through to the `*err = (int) val` case, which we do not want. (Why is it called “err”? That suggests an error, but this is for returning the correct value, is it not?) These tests should be structured so that **if** the value is in range, **then** it is converted, **else** an error is reported. Then NaNs flow to the error path. Or NaNs could be tested for separately.

Comment: This code assumes the minimum integer value is the negative of a power of two, but the C standard does not require that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for your comments, very appreciated (I have edited the variables for readability). Regarding rounding, the problem is even worse from the moment we are using floating-point numbers, I mean, the `double` variable and the hard-code number may be different, so the starting point may be already wrong.

Comment: and this assumes that `CHAR_BIT == 1` which may be not the case

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is to find `min_double_to_int` and `max_double_to_int`, the smallest and largest `double`, respectively, that can be converted to an `int`.

The portable conversion function itself can be written in C11 as

```
int double_to_int(const double value, int *err)
{
    if (!isfinite(value)) {
        if (isnan(value)) {
            if (err) *err = ERR_NAN;
            return 0;
        } else
        if (signbit(value)) {
            if (err) *err = ERR_NEG_INF;
            return INT_MIN;
        } else {
            if (err) *err = ERR_POS_INF;
            return INT_MAX;
        }
    }

    if (value < min_double_to_int) {
        if (err) *err = ERR_TOOSMALL;
        return INT_MIN;
    } else
    if (value > max_double_to_int) {
        if (err) *err = ERR_TOOLARGE;
        return INT_MAX;
    }

    if (err) *err = 0;
    return (int)value;
}
```

Before the above function is first used, we need to assign `min_double_to_int` and `max_double_to_int`.

EDITED on 2018-07-03: Rewritten approach.

We can use a simple function to find the smallest power of ten that is at least as large as `INT_MAX`/`INT_MIN` in magnitude. If those are smaller than `DBL_MAX_10_EXP`, the range of `double` is greater than the range of `int`, and we can cast `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` to `double`.

Otherwise, we construct a string containing the decimal representation of `INT_MAX`/`INT_MIN`, and use [`strtod()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtod.3.html) to convert them to `double`. If this operation overflows, it means the range of `double` is smaller than the range of `int`, and we can use `DBL_MAX`/`-DBL_MAX` as `max_double_to_int` and `min_double_to_int`, respectively.

When we have `INT_MAX` as a `double`, we can use a loop to increment that value using `nextafter(value, HUGE_VAL)`. The largest value that is finite, and rounded down using `floor()` still yields the same `double` value, is `max_double_to_int`.

Similarly, when we have `INT_MIN` as a double, we can use a loop to decrement that value using `nextafter(value, -HUGE_VAL)`. The largest value in magnitude that is still finite, and rounds up (`ceil()`) to the same `double`, is `min_double_to_int`.

Here is an example program to illustrate this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>

static double  max_double_to_int = -1.0;
static double  min_double_to_int = +1.0;

#define  ERR_OK        0
#define  ERR_NEG_INF  -1
#define  ERR_POS_INF  -2
#define  ERR_NAN      -3
#define  ERR_NEG_OVER  1
#define  ERR_POS_OVER  2

int double_to_int(const double value, int *err)
{
    if (!isfinite(value)) {
        if (isnan(value)) {
            if (err) *err = ERR_NAN;
            return 0;
        } else
        if (signbit(value)) {
            if (err) *err = ERR_NEG_INF;
            return INT_MIN;
        } else {
            if (err) *err = ERR_POS_INF;
            return INT_MAX;
        }
    }

    if (value < min_double_to_int) {
        if (err) *err = ERR_NEG_OVER;
        return INT_MIN;
    } else
    if (value > max_double_to_int) {
        if (err) *err = ERR_POS_OVER;
        return INT_MAX;
    }

    if (err) *err = ERR_OK;
    return (int)value;
}


static inline double  find_double_max(const double  target)
{
    double  next = target;
    double  curr;

    do {
        curr = next;
        next = nextafter(next, HUGE_VAL);
    } while (isfinite(next) && floor(next) == target);

    return curr;
}


static inline double  find_double_min(const double  target)
{
    double  next = target;
    double  curr;

    do {
        curr = next;
        next = nextafter(next, -HUGE_VAL);
    } while (isfinite(next) && ceil(next) == target);

    return curr;
}


static inline int  ceil_log10_abs(int  value)
{
    int  result = 1;

    while (value < -9 || value > 9) {
        result++;
        value /= 10;
    }

    return result;
}


static char *int_string(const int value)
{
    char    *buf;
    size_t   max = ceil_log10_abs(value) + 4;
    int      len;

    while (1) {
        buf = malloc(max);
        if (!buf)
            return NULL;

        len = snprintf(buf, max, "%d", value);
        if (len < 1) {
            free(buf);
            return NULL;
        }

        if ((size_t)len < max)
            return buf;

        free(buf);
        max = (size_t)len + 2;
    }
}

static int int_to_double(double *to, const int ivalue)
{
    char   *ival, *iend;
    double  dval;

    ival = int_string(ivalue);
    if (!ival)
        return -1;

    iend = ival;
    errno = 0;
    dval = strtod(ival, &iend);
    if (errno == ERANGE) {
        if (*iend != '\0' || dval != 0.0) {
            /* Overflow */
            free(ival);
            return +1;
        }
    } else
    if (errno != 0) {
        /* Unknown error, not overflow */
        free(ival);
        return -1;
    } else
    if (*iend != '\0') {
        /* Overflow */
        free(ival);
        return +1;
    }
    free(ival);

    /* Paranoid overflow check. */
    if (!isfinite(dval))
        return +1;

    if (to)
        *to = dval;

    return 0;
}

int init_double_to_int(void)
{
    double  target;

    if (DBL_MAX_10_EXP > ceil_log10_abs(INT_MAX))
        target = INT_MAX;
    else {
        switch (int_to_double(&target, INT_MAX)) {
        case 0:  break;
        case 1:  target = DBL_MAX; break;
        default: return -1;
        }
    }

    max_double_to_int = find_double_max(target);

    if (DBL_MAX_10_EXP > ceil_log10_abs(INT_MIN))
        target = INT_MIN;
    else {
        switch (int_to_double(&target, INT_MIN)) {
        case 0:  break;
        case 1:  target = -DBL_MAX; break;
        default: return -1;
        }
    }

    min_double_to_int = find_double_min(target);

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int     i, val, err;
    double  temp;

    if (init_double_to_int()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "init_double_to_int() failed.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("(int)max_double_to_int = %d\n", (int)max_double_to_int);
    printf("(int)min_double_to_int = %d\n", (int)min_double_to_int);
    printf("max_double_to_int = %.16f = %a\n", max_double_to_int, max_double_to_int);
    printf("min_double_to_int = %.16f = %a\n", min_double_to_int, min_double_to_int);

    temp = nextafter(max_double_to_int, 0.0);
    for (i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
        val = double_to_int(temp, &err);
        printf("(int)(max_double_to_int %+d ULP)", i);
        switch (err) {
        case ERR_OK:       printf(" -> %d\n", val); break;
        case ERR_POS_OVER: printf(" -> overflow\n"); break;
        case ERR_POS_INF:  printf(" -> infinity\n"); break;
        default:           printf(" -> BUG\n");
        }
        temp = nextafter(temp, HUGE_VAL);
    }

    temp = nextafter(min_double_to_int, 0.0);
    for (i = 1; i >= -1; i--) {
        val = double_to_int(temp, &err);
        printf("(int)(min_double_to_int %+d ULP)", i);
        switch (err) {
        case ERR_OK:       printf(" -> %d\n", val); break;
        case ERR_NEG_OVER: printf(" -> overflow\n"); break;
        case ERR_NEG_INF:  printf(" -> infinity\n"); break;
        default:           printf(" -> BUG\n");
        }
        temp = nextafter(temp, -HUGE_VAL);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. (nan/inf handling omitted for brevity)

```
int convert(double x) {
   if (x == INT_MAX) {
     return INT_MAX;
   } else if (x > INT_MAX) {
     err = ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE; 
     return INT_MAX;
   } else if (x == INT_MIN) {
     return INT_MIN;
   } else if (x < INT_MIN)
     err = ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE;
     return INT_MIN;
   } else {
     return x;
   }
}
```

Explanation.

The edge cases, as explained in one of the linked answers, are when `INT_MAX` is not representable as `double` exactly, and is rounded up when converted to `double`, and a symmetric case one with `INT_MIN`. That's the case when `if (x > INT_MAX)` fails. That is, the comparison returns `false`, but we still cannot convert `x` to `int` directly.

What the linked answer fails to recognise is that there's only one double number that fails the test, namely `(double)INT_MAX`, and we can easily catch this case by checking for `x == INT_MAX` explicitly.

**Edit** As noted in the comments, this may fail if `INT_MAX` or `INT_MIN` is outside of the range of `double`. While extremely unlikely, this is not precluded by the standard. In such an implementation, the conversion is just `(int)x`. It should be easier to detect such an implementation at configuration time than at run time. If the latter is absolutely needed, one can perform this operation *once*:

```
static int need_simple_conversion = 0;
char* str = malloc(sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT+1);
sprintf (str, "%d", INT_MAX);
errno = 0;
if (strtod(s, NULL) == HUGE_VAL && errno == ERANGE) {
   // INT_MAX overflows double => double can never overflow int
   need_simple_conversion = 1;
}
```

Then

```
if (need_simple_conversion)
    return x;
else { // as above
```

For the paranoid among us, do this with INT_MIN too and perform the check separately for positive and negative doubles.

Comment: Hum. One issue here is that INT_MAX could be outside the range of a double. My personal take on that is that the C standard is defective on that quixotic possibility.

Comment: @Bathsheba you'd need about 128 bit integers for that, *and* `double` that is actually IEEE single-precision float or smaller. This combination, while theoretically possible, is not likely to occur in this here Universe before its thermal death.

Comment: @Bathsheba one could check for this with `DBL_MAX_EXP > sizeof(int)*CHAR_BITS-1` or something.

Comment: Will that be by fire or ice? (Higg's Boson dependent?) On the conversion question, the last sequential whole number exactly represented by a `double` value is `9,007,199,254,740,992` which is orders of magnitude beyond `INT_MAX`, so how is `INT_MAX` not representable as a `double` in the test `x > INT_MAX`? All integer values before that are exactly represented by a `double`.

Comment: int it could be also 64.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The C standard doesn't mandate any of these numbers. There's no upper limit on INT_MAX. OTOH `double` is allowed to be as small as `float`.

Comment: OK, I get it, the issue is what the standard mandates -- thus your thermal end comment -- which I agree with.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin my proposed method should also work for other types, e.g. `long long` and `float`, where the max integer value is not exactly representable as a floating point type in most implementations.

Comment: @n.m. Regarding your first comment, that has a Bill Gates 640k ring to it ;-) With a particularly hostile mantissa / exponent ratio it's in touching distance of an 128 bit `int`. So I *still* think it's an impossible task in portable C. (But would very much like to be proven wrong by counter-example).

Comment: @Bathsheba when we move to 128-bit ints we'll likely also move to 128-bit or larger doubles, so this is still unlikely to happen in a normal implementation. A *hostile* implementation can be detected like I propose above. In such implementation the conversion is just `(int)x`. This is probably not needed for *practical* portability, which is why I can't be bothered to figure out the exact condition.

Comment: @n.m. Of course you're absolutely correct. But, it's still not possible to do it *portably*, I think.

Comment: @n.m one of my dreams is to implement DeathStation-9000 (and conquer the world with it).

Comment: the C standard mandated `FLT_DIG >= 6` and `DBL_DIG >= 10`, so `double` can't be IEEE-754 single precision

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, the basic problem distills to:   is double->int->double an identity for the values of INT_MAX and INT_MIN.   Interestingly, C has a way of expressing this:

```
int isok(int val) {
   double dv = val;
   int iv = dv;
   return val == iv;
}
```

From this, a much condensed form of the above answers can work, as you can use this to determine whether INT_MAX,INT_MIN are reasonably comparable, thus:

```
if (isok(INT_MAX) && isok(INT_MIN) && f >= INT_MIN && f < INT_MAX) {
     // do your weirdo float stuff here...
}
```

but, of course, relying upon C’s rigorous type conversion system gives the compiler free license to reformat your disk, so maybe stuff it through printf/scanf instead.

Comment: In the case where `double dv = val;` rounds to a number of greater magnitude, `int iv = dv;` is undefined behavior. An example would be `INT_MAX` for 64-bit 2's-complement `int` and IEEE 754 double-precision `double`.