# Loss of precision for int to float conversion

Tags: c++, floating-point, type-conversion

In C++, the conversion of an integer value of type `I` to a floating point type `F` will be exact — as `static_cast<I>(static_cast<F>(i)) == i` — if the range of `I` is a part of the range of integral values of `F`.

Is it possible, and if yes how, to calculate the loss of precision of `static_cast<F>(i)` (without using another floating point type with a wider range)?

As a start, I tried to code a function that would return if a conversion is safe or not (safe, meaning no loss of precision), but I must admit I am not so sure about its correctness.

```
template <class F, class I>
bool is_cast_safe(I value)
{
    return std::abs(alue) < std::numeric_limits<F>::digits;
}

std::cout << is_cast_safe<float>(4) << std::endl; // true
std::cout << is_cast_safe<float>(0x1000001) << std::endl; // false
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Convert to float and back to int, and see if what you got back was what you started with.

Comment: One thing you may want to consider here: nowadays, almost everything uses IEEE-754 floating point. So there is no need to be tricky here, it is well known, at which point int->float conversion starts losing precision. There is `is_iec559`, which can be used for checking IEEE-754 conformance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_cast_safe` can be implemented with:

```
static const F One = 1;
F ULP = std::scalbn(One, std::ilogb(value) - std::numeric_limits<F>::digits + 1);
I U = std::max(ULP, One);
return value % U;
```

This sets `ULP` to the value of the least digit position in the result of converting `value` to `F`. `ilogb` returns the position (as an exponent of the floating-point radix) for the highest digit position, and subtracting one less than the number of digits adjusts to the lowest digit position. Then `scalbn` gives us the value of that position, which is the ULP.

Then `value` can be represented exactly in `F` if and only if it is a multiple of the ULP. To test that, we convert the ULP to `I` (but substitute 1 if it is less than 1), and then take the remainder of `value` divided by the ULP (or 1).

Also, if one is concerned the conversion to `F` might overflow, code can be inserted to handle this as well.

Calculating the actual amount of the change is trickier. The conversion to floating-point could round up or down, and the rule for choosing is implementation-defined, although round-to-nearest-ties-to-even is common. So the actual change cannot be calculated from the floating-point properties we are given in `numeric_limits`. It must involve performing the conversion and doing some work in floating-point. This definitely can be done, but it is a nuisance. I think an approach that should work is:

- Assume `value` is non-negative. (Negative values can be handled similarly but are omitted for now for simplicity.)
- First, test for overflow in conversion to `F`. This in itself is tricky, as the behavior is undefined if the value is too large. Some similar considerations were addressed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51107035/298225) to a question about safely converting from floating-point to integer (in C).
- If the value does not overflow, then convert it. Let the result be `x`. Divide `x` by the floating-point radix `r`, producing `y`. If `y` is not an integer (which can be tested using `fmod` or `trunc`) the conversion was exact.
- Otherwise, convert `y` to `I`, producing `z`. This is safe because `y` is less than the original `value`, so it must fit in `I`.
- Then the error due to conversion is `(z-value/r)*r + value%r`.

Answer (score 0):

`I loss = abs(static_cast<I>(static_cast<F>(i))-i)` should do the job. The only exception if `i`'s magnitude is large, so `static_cast<F>(i)` would generate an out-of-I-range `F`.

(I supposed here that `I abs(I)` is available)

Comment: This fails if `static_cast<F>(i)` has rounded up so that it exceeds the maximum value of the integer type. For example, if `i` is an `int32_t` with value 2147483647, and `F` is the common 32-bit `float`, then `static_cast<F>(i)` will be 2147483648, and `static_cast<I>(static_cast<F>(i))` will overflow, and the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: yes, that's what I meant by the sentence "The only exception...". But you've explained it better :)