# How to subclass QSpinBox so it could have int64 values as maxium and minimum

Tags: qt, qspinbox

I need to implement a `QSpinBox` control which should be able to process `int64` values as it's minimum & maximum values. Current implementation only supports `int32` values.

End of the day my `QSpinBox` should accept any value between 
9223372036854775807 and -9223372036854775808

What do I need to do, if I'm to achieve this by subclassing `QAbstractSpinbox` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Derive from `QAbstractSpinBox`.
2. Add a `QValidator` to the `QLineEdit` to only allow valid int64 values.
3. Add a property called `value` to provide access to the int64 member that actually holds the value.
4. Reimplment `stepBy(int steps)` to modify the number.
5. Implement the methods and properties specific to `QSpinBox` that you are interested in (minimum/maximum limits, prefix, suffix, etc).

Essentially you are maintaining two states: one is the actual int64 value, the other is the text held by the `QLineEdit`.  Usually this is just updated by:

```
lineEdit()->setText(QString::number(myNumber));
```

But it will have to be tweaked slightly if the user wants a prefix or suffix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how Can I create a validator to validate Int64 range, QIntValidator only provides int32 ?

Comment: I guess I have to subclass the QValidator and create my own Int64Validator

Comment: Why don't you use a QDoubleSpinbox with no decimals ? You wouldn't need to derive from QAbstractSpinbox.

Comment: @e.d. Because a double only 52 mantissa bits.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double