# Set specific values in a QSpinBox

Tags: qt, qspinbox

I have a widget containing a `QSpinBox`. This widget also has a `QVector<int> Values`. What I would like to do is get the `QSpinBox` to display values issued **from `Values` only**.

At first I thought that a new slot and signal in my widget would do the trick, something like

slot :

```
void ChangeSomeValue()
{
    // QVector<int> Values;
    // int Index;
    int val = Values[ Index ];
    emit( SomeValueChanged( val ) );
}
```

connects :

```
connect( UI->MySpinBox, SIGNAL( valueChanged(int) ), this, SLOT( ChangeSomeValue() ) );
connect( this, SIGNAL( SomeValueChanged(int ) ), UI->MySpinBox, SLOT( setValue(int) ) );
```

But then several problems arise :

1. `QSpinBox` emit another `valueChanged` after I call its setValue, resulting in an infinite loop (until my `QVector` explodes).
2. I still have to find a way to keep track of Index, depending on which of the `QSpinBox` arrows was clicked (up or down... I don't even think this is possible).

So my solution, with its problems, seems to be a dead end. Any idea?. I'd like to stick to `QSpinBox`, if possible.

Thanks !

**[EDIT]**

Subclassing :

```
class SpinBox : public QSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SpinBox(const QVector<int> & values, QWidget * parent = 0) :
        QSpinBox(parent),
        mValues(values),
        mIndex(0)
    {
        qSort(mValues);
        setMinimum(mValues.at(0));
        setMaximum(mValues.at(mValues.size() - 1));
        setValue(mValues.at(0));
    }

protected:
    void stepBy(int steps) // re-implementaion
    {
        mIndex += steps;
        mIndex = qBound(0, mIndex, mValues.size() - 1);
        setValue(mValues.at(mIndex));
    }

private:
    QVector<int>    mValues;
    int             mIndex;
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Would suggest writing your own class to do it by sub-classing QAbstractSpinBox.

Maybe take a look at the accepted answer on this question:
[How to subclass QSpinBox so it could have int64 values as maxium and minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654769/how-to-subclass-qspinbox-so-it-could-have-int64-values-as-maxium-and-minimum?rq=1)

Comment: Then it may be faster to switch to something like QComboBox. At first I actually started to write the sub-class you suggest, but it looked like a waste of time. Thanks anyway !

Comment: Well its probably not a waste of time if you might use this class a lot.  Sounds quite useful to me.

Comment: Well, I'll probably give it a chance this week end, if I find some time to spare. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: @CTZStef Nice.  Easier than doing a full subclass or QAbstractSpinBox

Answer (score 2):

> QSpinBox emit another valueChanged after I call its setValue, resulting in an infinite loop (until my QVector explodes).

You can prevent this by using QObject::blockSignals(). Make sure to unblock signals afterwards.

> I still have to find a way to keep track of Index, depending on which of the QSpinBox arrows was clicked (up or down... I don't even think this is possible).

Well, I suppose you can store the old value in a member variable, and when QSpinBox emits `valueChanged()`, you can compare the new to the old value to figure out whether the up or the down arrow was pressed.

That said, I don't know if that's enough to make `QSpinBox` behave like you want, correcting the value after it was changed once is a bit hacky. Subclassing `QAbstractSpinbox` might be better indeed.