# Single-function comparison of Union values

Tags: c++, unions

I have a `union` defined as follows:

```
union V64
{
    double f64;
    __int64 i64;
    unsigned __int64 u64;
};
```

I'd like to do a lazy comparison (equality and inequality) of a 8-byte value of unknown type against another `V64` of known type. Will comparing the `i64` of two `V64`s consistently give me the expected result, regardless of the underlying type? For example:

```
V64 a.u64 << 9007199254740993+500;  //pseudo-code reading raw bytes
V64 b.u64 << -9007199254740993-501; //pseudo-code reading raw bytes
if(a.i64 > b.i64)
{/*do stuff*/}
```

Comparing `u64` breaks down when one is negative and `f64` breaks down when the value exceeds [`double`'s `int` storage (2^53 +1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double). Comparing `i64` appears to work, but there might be a case I haven't considered.

Comment: It doesn't even compile!

Comment: Edited my question to remove the trivial portion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you assign to two members of the same type, you can compare them:

```
a.f64 = 5.0;
b.f64 = -1.0;

if (a.f64 < b.f64) { /* ... */ }
```

You can only read the union member that was last written to. So you could compare `a.f64` and `c.u64`, but that would just promote both values to `double`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What do you mean I can only read the member last written to? See my question's edits for some clarification.

Comment: @Phlucious: It is undefined behaviour to read an inactive union member (i.e. any which wasn't the last to be written to).

Comment: Ah, I see. So even though it _appears_ to work on MSVC2010, it might not on gcc? Also, I just fixed a typo in the example.

Comment: So what's the alternative for truly "correct" code? A `void*` with `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: @Phlucious: Err.. not write code like that? I don't know. What's the problem we're trying to solve?

Comment: lol, fair enough. I want to read 8+8 bytes from disc, which can be two `UINT64`s, two `INT64`s, or two `double`s, and then compare the two values against each other to know which is greater without writing 3 different comparisons. I get the results using the union by reading as a UINT64 and comparing as a INT64, but apparently that behavior is undefined C++. I'm not worried about endian-ness.

Comment: @Phlucious: Going just by what you said, that makes no sense. *How* do you know whether you're reading an int or a double? Once you know that, everything else will fall into place (i.e. read directly into the correct type).

Comment: @Phlucious: This strikes me as a classical XZ problem: You're asking about X, even though you think that you want to solve Y, but in truth you need to solve Z.

Comment: Went back through my old questions and found this answer I never accepted. Basically, I was trying to use unions in an undefined way.