# Joining the digits of a numeric vector

Tags: matlab

I'm fairly new to Matlab, although not to programming. I'm trying to hash a string, and get back a single value that acts as a unique id for that string. I'm using this [DataHash](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31272-datahash) function from FileExchange which returns the hash as an integer vector. So far the best solution I've found for converting this to a single numeric value goes:

```
hash_opts.Format = 'uint8';
hash_vector = DataHash(string, hash_opts);
hash_string = num2str(hash_vector);
% Use a simple regex to remove all whitespace from the string,
% takes it from '1 2 3 4' to '1234'
hash_string = regexprep(hash_string, '[\s]', '');
hashcode = str2double(hash_string);
```

A reproducible example that doesn't depend on DataHash:

```
hash_vector = [1, 23, 4, 567];
hash_string = num2str(hash_vector);
% Use a simple regex to remove all whitespace from the string,
% takes it from '1 2 3 4' to '1234'
hash_string = regexprep(hash_string, '[\s]', '');
hashcode = str2double(hash_string); % Output: 1234567
```

Are there more efficient ways of achieving this, without resorting to a regex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Matlab's regex implementation isn't particularly fast. I suggest that you use [`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html):

```
hashcode = str2double(strrep(hash_string,' ',''));
```

Alternatively, you can use a string creation method that doesn't insert spaces in the first place:

```
hash_vector = [1, 23, 4, 567];
hash_string = str2double(sprintf('%d',hash_vector))
```

Just make sure that your hash number is less than 2^53 or the [conversion to double might not be exact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double).

Comment: @OlegKomarov: We were really thinking the same. Even down to double precision minutiae. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks. I think the hashes from both MD5 and SHA-1 can be greater than 2^53, so I appreciate the warning.

Comment: @horchler Haha, I was surprised myself!

Answer (score 3):

I'v seen there's already an answer - though it loses precission as it omits leading 0s - I'm not really sure if it will cause you troubles but I wouldn't want to rely on it.

As you output as uint8 why don't you use hex values instead - this will give you the exactly same number. Converting back is also easy using dec2hex.

```
hash_vector = [1, 23, 4, 253]
hash_str=sprintf('%02x',hash_vector); % to assure every 8 bit use 2 hex digits!
hash_dig=hex2dec(hash_str)
```

btw. - your sampe hash contains 567 - an impossible number in uint8.

---

Having looked at  DataHash the question would also be why not use base64 or hex in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to include some context because I knew there were multiple points I might have gone wrong, it's probably more sensible to use the hex values write from the start.