# What is the maximum auto generated id in Google App Engine datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

What is the  maximum auto generated id in Google App Engine datastore?

*Why this question?*

I would like to show a more user-friendy id to my customer in a format like **####-####-####** using the alphabet:

```
 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

*the character O has been removed to avoid confusion with the digit 0.*

I need to know how many groups of ### are needed to represent all the ids.

Comment: Alternatively, you can allocate a range of numeric IDs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#numeric_keys

Comment: see **_MAX_LONG** for numeric IDs and **_MAX_KEYPART_BYTES** for string IDs here:  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python/blob/master/ndb/key.py

Answer (score 8, accepted):

2^53 (the integer portion of a 64-bit float)

Comment: I'd guess you ment 2^63, not 2^53.

Comment: 2^53 is correct, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double

Comment: But auto generated IDs are signed int64's not floats.

Comment: Most JSON implementations store the numbers in a 64-bit float. Datastore ids are deliberately capped to not exceed what most JSON implementations can represent.

Answer (score 3):

From the document "How Entities and Indexes are stored" (https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown/):

> The first component of a key is the entity kind – the model or class name given to a model object (str). The next component is an ID (int64) or key name (str). Note that entities can have a numerical ID or key name but not both

So it sounds like the ID, if an integer is 64 bit, and I believe it is signed, so you would have 2^63 - 1 as the maximum value (9223372036854775807).

and from this part of the datastore (python) documentation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Assigning_identifiers

> The Datastore can be configured to generate auto IDs using two different auto id policies:
>
> **The default policy generates a random sequence of IDs that are approximately uniformly 
>   distributed. Each ID can be up to 16 digits long**.
>
> The legacy policy creates a sequence of non-consecutive smaller integer IDs.

This would be 16 decimal digits (and hence 16 characters in length)