# Matlab indexing uses floating point numbers?

Tags: matlab, class, floating-point, indexing, integer

In short, my question is:

Is a double in Matlab really a double, or is it a class with the additional property to act as an integer?

And here is the context and motivation for the question :)

```
>> 1:4
ans =
     1     2     3     4
>> class(ans)
ans =
double
```

Just doing this creates a double...

```
>> 1.00:4.00
ans =
     1     2     3     4
>> class(ans)
ans =
double
```

...as does this, even though it's printed as integers.

The floating point nature of the numbers only shows when greater numerical uncertainty is introduced.

```
>> acosd(cosd(1:4))
ans =
     0.999999999999900   1.999999999999947   3.000000000000045   4.000000000000041
```

**Is a double in Matlab really a double, or is it a class with the additional property to act as an integer?**

---

A vector defined with "integers" (which of course really is doubles), it can be used to index another vector, which is usually a property of integers.

```
>> A = [9 8 7 6]
A =
     9     8     7     6
>> idx = [4 3 2 1]
idx =
     4     3     2     1
>> class(idx)
ans =
double
>> A(idx)
ans =
     6     7     8     9
```

I also tried `A(acosd(cosd(1:4)))` which does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a double, but your [command prompt `format`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) gives you the most compact view.  Specifically,

```
format short
```

But you can change it to always display decimals, and lots of them, with

```
format longEng
```

There are many other options on the `format` help page.

Interestingly, [you can use non-integer numbers as indexes with the `colon` operator](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-FA9A2S/index.html?solution=1-FA9A), but it will warn.  I would take this warning *seriously* as this indexing behavior is odd.

As I mentioned in my comments, the reason it is OK for MATLAB to use `double`s for indexing has to do with [the largest value of an integer that can be specified without losing precision in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flintmax.html). Double precision (64-bit) floating point numbers can exactly represent integers up to 2^53 (9,007,199,254,740,992) without losing any accuracy. The [maximum array size allowed by MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-IHYHFZ/index.html) is far below this number, so there is no risk of indexing errors as a result of floating point precision.

Comment: But how come I can index with the doubles when defined as `[4 3 2 1]`, but not when they have (presumeable) lesser floating point accuracy (compared to when they ware originalley defined)? Guess Matlab should only distinguish from the class, not the number itself?

Comment: @NovicePhysicist `double`s do not lose accuracy until above 53-bits, so MATLAB lets you use them (numbers over 9,007,199,254,740,992 will lose precision).  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1848762/2778484).

Comment: @NovicePhysicist If you do a test with something like `x=rand(4,1); x(1.6:2.4), x(1.2:2.6)`  there is clearly some rounding going on (truncation?).  I don't know what happens when you try to give an index over about 9 quadrillion, but I think that is over the [maximum array size in MATLAB on every platform listed](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-IHYHFZ/index.html).

Comment: Thank you, I have a better understanding of this now... though I still feel a bit uncompfortable using floating point numbers for indexing :)

Comment: @NovicePhysicist Agreed.  Don't do it!  ;)

Comment: Guess that I can't really avoid it, unless i do something like `A = [1 2 3 4]; idx = int8([1 3 2 4]); A(idx);`?

Comment: @NovicePhysicist - Oh, well that is not worth doing.  I meant avoiding decimal valued (not integral-valued) indexing.  It's fine to use doubles to represent indexes because it warns if there are fractional components.

Answer (score 4):

In MATLAB, all numeric literals (i.e. numbers in the text of your program) are interpreted as double-precision. You must cast them explicitly to get any other type. It's worth remembering that IEEE floating point can exactly represent a wide range of integer values, up to [FLINTMAX](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/flintmax.html).

Comment: plus 1 for `flintmax`