# What's wrong with this string_to_number function?

Tags: c++, string

I have a string_to_number function that converts string to double. Why is this not working in this case?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

double string_to_number( string text )
{
    double value;
    istringstream ( text ) >> value;
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    string text = "1234567890987654321";
    double value = string_to_number( text );
    cout << fixed << setprecision( 0 ) << value << endl; // 123456789098765400 ??? What happened to "321" ?!!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the function. [Read this](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf).

Comment: Do you *have* to write your own? Can't you use e.g. [`std::stoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (or [`std::stold`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)).

Comment: Have you try to do `std::cout << 1234567890987654321.` the same way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That number is too large to fit in a single double, so its being truncated.

Comment: @M.HosainMa'refat You can't.

Comment: you may be able to use a `long double`, otherwise look into using a library like [GNU GMP](https://gmplib.org/‎)

Comment: It's not that it's too large, it's just too precise.

Comment: fixed it with 'long double'! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [IEEE format for a double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64).

There's a limit when storing integers **without losing precision** into doubles as this answer greatly summarizes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848762/1938163

Loss of precision first occurs with 2^53+1 and your number is exactly greater than that

```
   9007199254740993
1234567890987654321
```

Answer (score 1):

the number is just too large for the double representation, so it's being truncated. Mind that the size of 'long double' type is architecture dependent. 
Please look here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx): `sizeof(double)=8` and `sizeof(long double)=8`, whilst the same check implemented on Debian 64bits shows `sizeof(double)=8` and `sizeof(long double)=16`.

Perhaps more portable way would be using external libraries dealing with big numbers, like 
[boost multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html) or GNU GMP