# Have MATLAB print full 2^64 value

Tags: matlab, printing

I'm trying to print the value:

```
(2^32 - 1) * (2^32 - 1)
```

in MATLAB and have it display all 20 digits. I've tried

```
fomat long
```

and

```
sprintf('%20d',ans)
```

Neither of these are getting the results I want and print:

```
1.844674406511962e+19
```

or something to that effect. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right to expect `%d` to print an integer as an integer, requiring no precision or field width specification, rather than in exponential notation (`%e`). There is a reason why `sprintf` fails to display this integer as an integer. Here's why (and more).

From the [`sprintf` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html#input_argument_formatspec), this is the output format that `%d` specifies:

> Integer, **signed**; `%d` or `%i`;
>   Base 10

The keyword here is *signed*. This *does* specify an integer printed in decimal (base 10) notation, *but* the sign takes up one bit! The largest integer you (and `%d`) can represent with a **64-bit signed integer** (i.e. [`int64`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int64.html)) is **`2^63-1`** (check with [`intmax('int64')`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intmax.html)). And since `(2^32 - 1) * (2^32 - 1) > 2^63-1`, **`sprintf` falls back to exponential notation (`%e`)**. But don't take my word for it:

```
>> sprintf('%d',uint64(2^63)-1)
ans =
9223372036854775807
>> sprintf('%d',uint64(2^63))
ans =
9.223372e+18
```

**The solution** is to use the *unsigned* integer format: `%u`.

```
>> sprintf('%u',uint64(2^63))
ans =
9223372036854775808
```

With `(2^32 - 1) * (2^32 - 1)`, the issue is less subtle, but the solution is the same:

```
>> val = (2^32 - 1) * (2^32 - 1); % > 2^63-1
>> sprintf('%u',val)
ans =
18446744065119617024
```

This answers the question, but this is still *wrong*. This time it's not `sprintf`'s fault. Double precision (64-bit) floating point numbers can only represent integers [up to 2^53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double) *without loss of precision*<sup>1</sup>.  Since the default data type in MATLAB is `double`, `val` is stored as a `double`. To ensure no loss of precision, use the `uint64` type:

```
>> valUI = uint64(2^32 - 1) * uint64(2^32 - 1)
>> sprintf('%u',valUI)
ans =
18446744065119617025
```

Close. `double` almost got lucky.

<sup>1</sup>This value of 2^53 (or 9,007,199,254,740,992) can be verified by [`flintmax('double')`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flintmax.html).

Answer (score 1):

You must increase the precision, which is the number following the `.` in the format spec:

```
sprintf('%.20d',ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

To turn the scientific notation off, try this:

```
format long g
```