# How to display a 4 digit number in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

My matlab displays the value `1042` as `1.042e+003`

How do I get matlab to stop using the `e` notation and display a 4 digit number ( or longer )

More specifically, this is what I am trying to do :

```
title(sprintf('1st harmonic of I. Vpeak = %i', AmpHar(i)));
```

`AmpHar(i)` has the value `1042`. But in the plot title it gets displayed as `1.042e+003`

**Edit:**

of `AmpHar(i)` has a full value of `1042.3478`. But I would like matlab to display the value as `1042.34` in the title

Comment: %d or %f instead of %i?

Comment: %d and %i are the same.  It works for me.  Are you sure there aren't more decimals like 1042.05? Also try `sprintf` by itself (without `title`). Or `round` it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer to the edit is, to display the fractional component with the right decimal places, use `%f` and set the precision:

```
title(sprintf('1st harmonic of I. Vpeak = %.2f', AmpHar(i)));
```

Regarding the first question, you are using the correct format specifier for an integer (`%i` and `%d` are the same). The problem was that `AmpHar(i)` is not integer-valued, as it has a fractional component. When MATLAB's `sprintf` sees this, it switches to exponential notation (`%e`). Another interesting situation in which it will make this switch to exponential [if `%d` gets an integer larger than `2^63-1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22499366/2778484). See the solution there.