# Rounding double strangeness

Tags: java, floating-point, double, floor

it might be too late in the night, but I can't understand the behavior of this code:

```
public class DT {
static void theTest(double d){
    double e = Math.floor(d/1630)*1630;
    System.out.println(e-d);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    theTest(2*1630);
    theTest(2*1631);
    theTest(2*1629);
    theTest(8.989779443802325E18);
}
```

}

in my understangind, all 4 cases should be NON-positive, i.e. "e" is always <= "d", 
but I do get following output:

```
0.0
-2.0
-1628.0
1024.0
```

Why??.
as this is same with FastMath, I suspect something double-specific? but could anyone explain me this?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of floating-point math.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html. You are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you get up into huge numbers, the doubles are spaced more widely than integers.  When you do a division in this range, the result can be rounded up or down.  So in your fourth test case, the result of the division `d/1630` is actually rounded up to the nearest available double.  Since this is a whole number, the call to `floor` does not change it.  Multiplying it by `1630` then gives a result that is larger than `d`.

**Edit**

This effect kicks in at 2^52.  Once you get past 2^52, there are no more non-integer doubles.  Between 2^52 and 2^53, the doubles are just the integers.  Above 2^53, the doubles are spaced more widely than the integers.

The result of the division in the question is `5515202112762162.576...`  which is between 2^52 and 2^53.  It is rounded to the nearest double, which is the same as the nearest integer, which is 5515202112762163.  Now, the `floor` does not change this number, and the multiplication by `1630` gives a result that is larger than `d`.

In summary, I guess the first sentence of the answer was a little misleading - you don't need the doubles to be spaced *more* widely than the integers for this effect to occur; you only need them to be spaced *at least as* widely as the integers.

With a value of `d` between 0 and 2^52 * 1630, the program in the question will never output a positive number.

Comment: Please define "huge numbers"

Comment: @AlexandreSantos [Larger than 2^53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double), which is approximately 9e15. Compare that with OP's number which is about 9e18.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: I think you are looking for the operation called `fmod` in other languages and `%` in Java. The `e - d` that you wish to compute could be computed allways of the correct sign and always lower than 1630 as `-(d % 1630.0)`.

---

> all 4 cases should be NON-positive

For an arbitrary double `d`, it is likely that `Math.floor(d/1630)*1630` would be less than `d`, but not necessary.

In order:

`d/1630` is the `double` nearest to the real d / 1630. It can be up to one half [ULP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) above the real d / 1630, and it can be arbitrarily close to an integer.

When `d` is large enough, `d/1630` is always an integer, because any large enough `double` is an integer. In other words, when `d` is large enough, `Math.floor(d/1630)` is identical to `d/1630`. This applies to your last example.

`d / 1630 * 1630` is the `double` nearest to the real multiplication of `d / 1630` by `1630`. It is one half ULP from the real result.

The two rounding operations in `d / 1630 * 1630` can both round up, and in this case, `d / 1630 * 1630` is larger than `d`. It wouldn't be expected to be larger than `d` by more than one `ULP(d)`.

If you want to compute a number that is guaranteed to be below the real d / 1630, you should either change the rounding mode to downward (not sure if Java lets you do this), or subtract one ULP from the result of `d / 1630` computed in the default round-to-nearest rounding mode. You can do the latter with the function [nextAfter](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_nextafter_double.htm).

Comment: thank you both, I will workaround for the numbers bigger than 9e15

Comment: @Павел Hum. The case `Math.floor(d/1630)*1630 > d` is likely to happen when `d` is larger than 9e15 or so, but it can happen with a `double` `d` in any range. Even in the range where not all doubles are integers, `d` / 1630 can be arbitrarily close to an integer for some doubles `d`, and then `e - d` can be positive. It is only less frequent, not impossible. Do you need me to show you an example with a small `d`?

Comment: OK, I trust you. In my program 1630 is also not a constant, it is rather double like d. So I just add back check and if Math.floor(d/1630)*1630 > d then I substract from the result the difference between "e" and "d" divided to 1630. This gives me a maximum error in 16 digit after decimal point, which I could afford

Comment: @Павел Aren't you looking for the operation that is called `fmod` in other languages and `%` in Java? I think that the result `e-d` that you want is `-(d % 1630.0)`. Also `%` is exact, so you won't get any problem with `d % 1630.0` being of the wrong sign or larger than `1630.0`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq "Do you need me to show you an example with a small `d`?" Not the same person, but I would like an example. @DavidWallace's answer above says it won't happen for `d` up to `2^52 * 1630`, which is pretty big, and it's all quite confusing.

Comment: @Boann I have quickly written code that looks for small counter-examples, and this code hasn't produced anything (I am executing in ideone and a full-scale brute-force search is not possible for me). However, I think that David Wallace's claim is an exaggeration, unless there is an argument that I don't see. With `d` above 2^52*1630, `d/1630` is automatically an integer, so `e-d>=0` has good chances to happen. With `d` smaller than this value, it can still happen that `d/1630` is an integer and that `e-d` ends up positive because of that.

Comment: @Boann FWIW my ideone Java code searched for counter-examples of the form `Math.nextAfter(N * 1630.0, 0)` for some integer N, so that `d / 1630` would be likely to round up to a floating-point number representing an integer, giving `e-d` a chance to be positive. If I get a chance I will write the search in C99 (for which I have a compiler).

Comment: @PascalCuoq (Deleted and reposted comment because I messed up.) Doubles are too big for an exhaustive search, I think, but I tried doing something equivalent with floats, and starting from 0, the first example it found for which `((float)(int)(f / 1630)) * 1630 > f` was 53,413,468.0, well *above* 2^22, the point equivalent to 2^52 for floats. But I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Comment: Pascal, this is interesting point, to be honest I never think that '%' is applicable to double, I thought it works only for integer.

as per your research, Boann, as I understand it is not matter of digits, it is more a matter of significant digits, for instance 1000 contain only 1 significant digit and could be represented by 1e+3, i.e. 1 in mantissa. and then 123.456 contains 6 significant digits.
this doesn't makes sence in my case as "d" and 1630 are both have zero fractional digits. but when I start to divide them, the number of significant digits increased. this is how I understand it

Comment: Downvoter, if the reason for the downvote is that you have an explanation for why my search for a small counter-example did not produce anything, I would be eager to hear it.