# How many integers divisible by 2 can be represented in IEEE-754 floating point with double precision?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

How many positive integers divisible by 2 can (could) be represented in IEEE-754 floating point with double precision?

Comment: 52 for double precision

Comment: Never mind, I was just taking my socks off to count a bit higher when I came across this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double which makes your question a near-duplicate and therefore closeworthy.

Comment: As it is a near-duplicate, can you actually answer the question or give me some hint in the comment?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Being making an attempt to answer the question, I do not find it a (near-)duplicate of either “larger bound below which all integers are representable” questions or your question, although it looks a bit like both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All even integers between -2<sup>54</sup> and 2<sup>54</sup> are representable as IEEE 754 double-precision numbers. All finite double-precision numbers larger in magnitude than 2<sup>54</sup> also happen to be even integers that should be counted. We count these two categories of numbers separately and then add the counts.

The first category represents all the numbers -(2<sup>54</sup>-2), -(2<sup>54</sup>-4), …, -2, 0, 2, 4, …, (2<sup>54</sup>-2).

The second category represents numbers such as 2<sup>54</sup>+4, 2<sup>54</sup>+8, as well as very large double-precision numbers such as 2<sup>1023</sup>. These numbers are IEEE 754 double-precision numbers that represent even integers, so they should be taken into account.
The reason the numbers in this category must be counted separately is that in this range, not all even integers are representable as double-precision IEEE 754 numbers (for instance, neither of 2<sup>54</sup>+2, 2<sup>54</sup>+6, and 2<sup>1023</sup>+1024 is representable).

---

The first category of numbers contains 2 * 2<sup>53</sup> - 1 items, from -(2<sup>54</sup>-2) to 2<sup>54</sup>-2.

The second category represents 2 * (1024 - 54) [binades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binade) (the factor two is because both negative binades and positive binades are being counted), that is, 2 * (1024 - 54) * 2<sup>52</sup> items.

This makes for a total of about 8754997675608244224 even integers in double-precision (give or take an off-by-one error in the computations).

Comment: There's a 53 bit mantissa. If 2^52 <= x < 2^53, the last bit of the mantissa has a value of 1, so x is an integer. If x >= 2^53, the last bit of the mantissa has a value of 2^k, k >= 1, so x is an even integer. All double precision floating point numbers >= 2^53 are even integers.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I believe you want `2 * (1024 - 54) * 2^52` for the count of values with absolute value in `[2^54, 2^1024)`.  I agree with the `2 * 2^53 - 1` for the count of even integers with absolute value strictly less than `2^54`.

Comment: Why each number from interval `[2^{54}...2^{54}]` is representable ? Why `2^{54}+2` is not representable ?