# How to stop matlab truncating long numbers

Tags: matlab

These two long numbers are the same except for the last digit.

`test = [];
test(1) = 33777100285870080;
test(2) = 33777100285870082;`

but the last digit is lost when the numbers are put in the array:

```
unique(test)

ans = 3.3777e+16
```

How can I prevent this? The numbers are ID codes and losing the last digit is screwing everything up.

Comment: are they *just used as ID codes* and *is there no arithmetic operation* done on them? if so storing as a string may be a better option...

Comment: I tried but I get a similar problem, num2str cuts off the last digit.

Comment: Typing ``eps(test(1))`` returns ``4``. This means the next greater distinguishable number from ``test(1)`` is ``test(1)+4``. You can verify by ``length(unique([test, test(1)+4]))`` returning ``2``. I believe you cannot solve this issue with using default numbers, but rather read (or input) the id as strings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Matlab uses 64-bit floating point representation by default for numbers. Those have a base-10 16-digit precision (more or less) and your numbers seem to exceed that.

Use something like [`uint64`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html) to store your numbers:

```
> test = [uint64(33777100285870080); uint64(33777100285870082)];
> disp(test(1));
   33777100285870080
> disp(test(2));
   33777100285870082
```

This is really a rounding error, not a display error. To get the correct strings for output purposes, use [`int2str`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/int2str.html), because, again, `num2str` uses a 64-bit floating point representation, and that has rounding errors in this case.

Comment: Running ``num2str(test)`` with your unit64 input returns the desired strings.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in to say it's not really a rounding error *per se*, it's an intrinsic limit of the floating point representation. The floating point standard cannot represent such a small difference between two numbers of that magnitude.

Comment: 64-bit floating-point type can represent exactly integers up to about 2^52. In your case the numbers are slightly larger than that, hence the problem. With one figure less you wouln't have had any problem. Try this for example: `33777100285870082-33777100285870080` (your numbers) gives `0` (wrong). But `3777100285870082-3777100285870080` (remove one figure) gives `2` (correct)

Comment: @Lefti just as long as your id's don't suddenly grow 3 or more digits longer, then this workaround also fails.

Comment: it should be ok, the ID code is always 17 digits long :)

Comment: @Dylan True, the "rounding" I mention, happens when the number is read by Matlab from text and converted into its internal representation. It's more of a "find the closest number that is representable" thing than pure base-10 rounding.

Answer (score 2):

To add more explanation to @rubenvb's solution, your values are greater than [`flintmax`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flintmax.html) for [IEEE 754 double precision floating-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), i.e, greater than `2^53`. After this point not all integers can be exactly represented as doubles. See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double).