# Import large integer in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to import a large integer (1000 digits) into matlab to run some calculations on it. However, when I import it I seem to loose accuracy due to the fact that matlab uses the scientific notation.
Is there any way that I can get the actual integer?

Here's the actual data I have to import:

```
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
```

Comment: Have you checked out [VPI](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic)?

Comment: John D'Errico has made some great contributions to Matlab and many are really solid so I would definitely check the link from Bruce above. Otherwise, I suspect you will have to write some kind of  `split/process/merge` algorithm, or write a custom class which handle 128 or 256 bits integers, because this is definitely more digits than any Matlab data type can handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a large integer cannot be represented in IEEE floating point standard. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848762/1586200) answer for the largest double that can be represented without losing precision (its `1.7977e+308`). That can be obtained by typing `realmax` in MATLAB.

You can use `vpi` (available here, as mentioned in comment) or you can use the MATLAB in-built [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html).

This is how you use `vpa`

```
R=vpa('7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450');
```

You can check the following:

```
vpa('R+1000-R')
```

The answer of the above is 1000 as expected. Do not forget to put your expression in quotes. Otherwise, you are passing inifinity to `vpa` instead of the 1000 digit number.

If you want to use `vpi`, its a beautiful toolbox, go ahead, download it. Go into its root directory and run the following command:

```
a=vpi('7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450')
```

Well, the advantage with `vpi` is as follows:

The output of `vpi`:

```
a=vpi(<<Your 1000 digit number in quotes>>); %output prints 1000 digits on screen.
```

The output of `vpa`:

```
R=vpa(<<Your 1000 digit number in quotes>>);
```

this prints:

```
R =

7.3167176531330624919225119674427e999
```

Also, with `vpi`, you can do something like this:

```
a=vpi('7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450')
b=a+1

b-a  %output of this yields 1.
```

I somehow cannot do the operation of `b-a` in `vpa` and obtain the answer `1`.