# Type conversion to vector in C++

Tags: c++

How to convert a `RepeatedField<google::protobuf::uint32>` to a `const std::vector<double>`?

Comment: Removing each element from RepeatedField and putting it in the vector should work.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: All (u)int32 values can be stored precisely in a double. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1848762/25488

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That should be easy, since repeated fields act as containers:

```
void foo(RepeatedField<google::protobuf::uint32> const & f)
{
    std::vector<double> v(f.begin(), f.end());

    // use v
}
```

Comment: @KarolyHorvath The solution is WLOG.

Comment: I am getting this error "expression vector iterator + offset out of range"

Comment: Yes... it is executing fine, but at one point it is throwing this error.

Comment: @Dosti: Then you have a mistake elsewhere, not fundamentally connected with the iterator interface of `RepeatedField`.