# Transforming two matrices into one matrix using binary numbers

Tags: matlab, binary

`A1` and `A2` are two arrays of integers with the same dimensions `6000x2000`.

I want to find a third matrix `B` by following these steps:

```
for i=1:1:6000
    for j=1:2000

        a1 = fliplr(dec2binvec(A1(i,j),14));  % Convert A1(i,j) to a binary vector
        a2 = fliplr(dec2binvec(A2(i,j),32));  % Convert A2(i,j) to a binary vector

        b = [a1 a2];

        B(i,j) = sum(b.*2.^(numel(b)-1:-1:0));  % Convert b to decimal


    end
end
```

**my problem is the computation time to find B**.

Is there a way to avoid loops in order to reduce the computation time ?

Example:

```
A1 = [2 3           A2 = [7 6
      4 5]                2 9]
```

`A1(1,1) = 2` and `A2(1,1) = 7`

`a1 = [0 0 0 1 0]` (eg 5 bits)   `a2 = [0 0 0 1 1 1]` (eg 6 bits)

```
b = [a1 a2] = [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]

B1(1,1) = sum(b.*2.^(numel(b)-1:-1:0)) = 135
```

Comment: Please post a small numeric example (say with 2x2 matrices), to clarify endianness etc

Comment: `dec2binvec` returns least significant bit first, but `b.*2.^(numel(b)-1:-1:0)` uses it as highest significant bit first. Did you verify you really get what you want with this code?

Comment: @LuisMendo : I added an example.

Comment: @bzak: The example and your code don't match, your code flips the bits.

Comment: @Daniel: I think I made a mistake with dec2binvec!

Comment: @Daniel: is there a function that returns highest significant bit first?

Comment: @bzak: Matlab always uses lowest significant bit first for logical vectors and highest significant bit first for string representations. If you need something else, use `fliplr(dec2binvec(2,6))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the example contains what you want. Simply use math ;)

```
A1 = [2 3;4,5]
A2=[7 6;2 9]
A1.*2^6+A2
```

Please be aware that doubles can hold up to 53 bits without precision loss. Recent versions of matlab support uint64. For even longer numbers check `vpa`, but `vpa` will result in slow code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double

Answer (score 4):

Using your example:

```
A1 = [2 3;           
      4 5];            
A2 = [7 6;
      2 9];
B=bitshift(A1,6)+A2
```

Output:

```
B =

   135   198
   258   329
```

Comment: Plus 1 for the `bitshift`.  I love that function.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks, I think for someone not used to working in binary it clarifies what multiplying by a power of 2 does to a number.

Comment: Yup it certainly does!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your example correctly, you only need to bit-shift `A1` (i.e. multiply by a power of 2):

```
M = 5; %// not used actually
N = 6;
B = A1 * 2^N + A2;
```

In your example, this gives

```
B =
   135   198
   258   329
```