# Why is Matlab Mod different from Wolfram Alpha

Tags: matlab, modulus, wolframalpha

688^79 mod 3337 = 1570.

When I tried this at wolfram alpha I got:
[image]

but When I entered the same thing in Matlab, I get 364 as the answer. I got to be doing something wrong.

[image]

Any light on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Some Overflow perhaps?

Comment: might be, let me run a quick test with a smaller value

Comment: with mod(4^3,24) both wolfram and matlab shows the same result == 16

Comment: 1570 is correct (calculated with python). Try `mod(double(688^79), 3337)`

Comment: nope, still getting me the 364

Comment: Just store them as `sym` and you will be able to calculate it correctly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is that Matlab uses `double` floating-point arithmetic by default. A number as large as 688^79 can't be represented accurately as a `double`. (The largest integer than can be accurately represented as a `double` is [of the order of 2^53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double)).

To obtain the right result you can use [symbolic variables](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/creating-symbolic-variables-and-expressions.html), which ensures you don't lose accuracy:

```
>> x = sym('688^79');
>> y = sym('3337');
>> mod(x, y)
ans =
1570
```

Comment: @JuanZamora ¡Un placer! :-)

Comment: Your example is using full symbolic math, not variable precision. There doesn't seem to be any reason to use variable precision here. Using variable precision with `vpa` means you have a finite, but adjustable, number of digits of precision. Maybe I don't understand what you're trying to say – you don't lose precision with respect to your specified value for `digits`, but in manu cases you absolutely can lose precision relative to the true value using `vpa`.

Comment: @LuisMendo check this one: 79^-1 mod 3220 = 1019 in wolfram. In matlab is just returning 1/79 = 0.0126... I tried the symbolic was, but no luck.

Comment: @JuanZamora That's a little more nuanced.  WolframAlpha appears to be solving the [modular inverse problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModularInverse.html) for the input `79^-1 mod 3220` (interpreted as `PowerMod[79,-1,3220]` but will solve the standard remainder problem for `1/79 mod 3220` (interpreted as `Mod[79^-1,3220]`).

Comment: @horchler You are completely right. I was trying several things and ended up not using `vpa`, but the explanation was wrong. Thanks! I've corrected it

Answer (score 3):

My calculator is sending me the same answer than Wolfram, it also calculated the value for 688^79 so I would tend to believe Wolfram is right. 
You probably have overrun the capacities of Matlab with such a huge number and it is why it did not send the right answer.

Comment: for the record your number is 147736096754175303230053677431108078993422779056521621788516135638187994995899192814258977221160914022825628299180402236602527982600775671266557420283463691946979929718178787089203370822514764608144873171356044647950190641152 Full stop