# Floating Point Addition / Multiplication / Division

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-conversion

I was doing some homework problems from my textbook and had a few questions on floating point rounding / precision for certain arithmetic operations.

If I have casted doubles from an int like so:

```
int x = random();
double dx = (double) x;
```

And let's say the variables **y**, **z**, **dy**, and **dz** follow the same format.

Then would operations like:

```
(dx + dy) + dz == dx + (dy + dz)
(dx * dy) * dz == dx * (dy * dz)
```

be associative? I know that if we have fractional representations, then it would not be associative because some precision will be lost due to rounding depending on which operands add / multiply each other. However, since these are casted from ints, I feel like the precision would not be a problem and that these can be associative?

And lastly, the textbook I'm using does not explain FP division at all so I was wondering if this statement was true, or at least just how floating point division works in general:

```
dx / dx == dz / dz
```

I looked this up online and I read in some areas like an operation like 3/3 can yield .999...9 but there wasn't enough information to explain how that happened or if it would vary with other division operations.

Comment: A good compiler should recognize dx/dx and not actually emit division instructions.

Comment: You can exactly represent any value up to 2^53 + 1 as a double.  Beyond that you run into rounding errors, even for integer types.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1848762/141172

Comment: you might remember, from your grade school days, that a number divided by itself is 1,  so the comparison 'may' work.  However, in general, floating point number should never be compared using '=='  instead, get the absolute values, get the difference, the check for the difference being less than some threashold

Comment: `(dx * dy) * dz == dx * (dy * dz)` a problem if the precision of a `double` < twice precision of an `int` - which is often the case.  `(dx + dy) + dz == dx + (dy + dz)` unlikely to be a problem as `double` precision certain more than `int` precision + 1.  `dx / dx == dz / dz` obvious problem should `dx==0` or `dz==0` .

Comment: When `dx * dy` and `dy * dz` great than `2^53`, it may be have precision issue. `double dx = (double)(INT_MAX);  double dy = (double)(INT_MAX - 0x111111);  double dz = (double)(INT_MAX - 0xabcd);` for `(dx * dy) * dz == dx * (dy * dz)` is false.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `int` is at most 32-bit, and `double` follows IEEE-754. `double` can store integer value at most 2<sup>53</sup> precisely.

---

In the case of addition:

```
(dx + dy) + dz == dx + (dy + dz)
```

Both sides of `==` will have their precise values, so it is associative.

---

While in the case of multiplication:

```
(dx * dy) * dz == dx * (dy * dz)
```

It's possible that the value is over 2<sup>53</sup>, so they are not guaranteed to be equal.

Comment: Just clarifying,  so the reason the max a double can store is 2^53 is because of the 52-bit mantissa + the implied leading 1?

Comment: To be clear: `double` can store all integers exactly `-pow(2,53) ... +pow(2,53)` --inclusive - just like a 54 bit signed integer or `int54_t`.

Answer (score 1):

You should understand that floating point numbers are typically internally represented as a sign bit, a fixed point mantissa (of 52 bits with an implied leading one for [IEEE 64-bit doubles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)), and a binary exponent (11 bits for IEEE doubles). You can think of the exponent as the "quantum" of math units for a given value.

The addition should be associative if the sums all fit into the mantissa without the exponent going above 2<sup>0</sup> == 1. If `random()` is producing 32-bit integers, a sum such as `(dx + dy) + dz` will fit, and the addition will be associative.

In the case of multiplication, it's easy to see that the product of 2 32-bit numbers may go well over 53 bits, so the exponent may need to go above 1 for the mantissa to contain the magnitude of the result, so associativity fails.

For division, in the particular case of `dx / dx`, the compiler may replace the expression with a constant 1.0 (perhaps after a zero check).

Comment: the exponent also has a built in offset (I'm thinking 256) to allow for both positive and negative exponents with out having to consume a bit for the sign

Comment: The exponent offset (usually called bias) is half the exponent range. For IEEE double with 11 bits of exponent, the bias is 1023. For IEEE single, it's 127.