# largest integer that can be stored in a double such that all integers less than can be accurately stored as well

Tags: binary, floating-point, double, precision, ieee-754

This is some more clarification to the question that was already answered some time ago here: [biggest integer that can be stored in a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double)

The top answer mentions that "the largest integer such that it and all smaller integers can be stored in IEEE 64-bit doubles without losing precision. An IEEE 64-bit double has 52 bits of mantissa, so I think it's 2^53:

because:

- 2<sup>53</sup> + 1 cannot be stored, because the 1 at the start and the 1 at the end have too many zeros in between.
- Anything less than 2<sup>53</sup> can be stored, with 52 bits explicitly stored in the mantissa, and then the exponent in effect giving you another one.
- 2<sup>53</sup> obviously can be stored, since it's a small power of 2.

Can someone clarify the first point? What does he mean by that? is he talking about for example if it were a 4 bit number 1000 + 0001, you can't store that in 4 bits? 2<sup>53</sup> is just the first bit 1 and the rest 0's right? how come you can't add a 1 to that without losing precision?

also, "The largest integer such that it and all smaller integers can be stored in IEEE". Is there some general rule such that if I wanted to find the largest n bit integer such that it and all smaller integers can be stored in IEEE, could I simply say that it is 2<sup>n</sup>? example if I were to find the largest 4 bit integers such that it and all integer below it can be represented, it would be 2^4?

Answer (score 0):

> is he talking about for example if it were a 4 bit number 1000 + 0001, you can't store that in 4 bits?

No, he is saying that you can't store that in 3 bits. Using the usual binary notation.

> 2<sup>53</sup> is just the first bit 1 and the rest 0's right?

Yes, and so are 1, 2, 4, …, 2<sup>53</sup>, 2<sup>54</sup>, 2<sup>55</sup>, …, 2<sup>123</sup>, 2<sup>124</sup>, … and also 0.125.

This is floating-point we are talking about. 2<sup>53</sup> is just an implicit 1 with all explicit significand bits 0, yes, but it is not the only number with this property. The crucial property is that the ULP for representing 2<sup>53</sup> is 2. So 2<sup>53</sup> can be represented as all powers of two that are in range, and 2<sup>53</sup>+1 cannot because the ULP is too large in that neighborhood.

> also, "The largest integer such that it and all smaller integers can be stored in IEEE". Is there some general rule such that if I wanted to find the largest n bit integer such that it and all smaller integers can be stored in IEEE, could I simply say that it is 2<sup>n</sup>?

Yes, in binary IEEE 754 floating-point, all “largest integer such that it and all smaller integers can be stored” are powers of two, and specifically 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the significand's width (counting the implicit bit).