# Inequalities in c not working

Tags: c, inequality

I'm learning c, and am confused as my code seems to evaluate ( 1e16 - 1 >= 1e16 ) as true when it should be false. My code is below, it returns

```
9999999999999999 INVALIDBIG\n
```

when I would expect it not to return anything. I thought any problems with large numbers could be avoided by using long long.

```
int main(void)
{
    long long z;

    z = 9999999999999999;

    if ( z >= 1e16 || z < 0 )
    {
        printf("%lli INVALIDBIG\n",z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Try `1e16LL`. Update: Actually the exponent notation is returning float type, so you can't append integer suffix to it. You better use integer constants

Comment: @EugeneSh. `float` or `double`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Floating point. The exact type doesn't really matter here, I believe..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because FP, compares and I can't be bothered to look up the dups.

Comment: Thanks for help all! Think I understand what's happening here now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1e16 is a double type literal value, and floats/doubles can be imprecise for decimal arithmetic/comparison (just one of many common examples: decimal 0.2). Its going to cast the long-long z upwards to double for the comparison, and I'm guessing the standard double representation can't store the precision needed (maybe someone else can demonstrate the binary mantissa/sign representations)

Try changing the 1e16 to (long double)1e16, it doesn't then print out your message. (update: or, as the other question-commenter added, change 1e16 to an integer literal)

Answer (score 1):

The doubles and floats can hold limited number of digits. In your case the double numbers with values `9999999999999999` and `1e16` have identical 8 bytes of hex representation. You can check them byte by byte:

```
long long z = 9999999999999999;
double dz1 = z;
double dz2 = 1e16;

/* prints 0 */
printf("memcmp: %d\n", memcmp(&dz1, &dz2, sizeof(double)));
```

So, they are equal.

Smaller integers can be stored in double with perfect precision. For example, see [Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) or [biggest integer that can be stored in a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double)

The maximum integer that can be converted to double exactly is 2<sup>53</sup> (`9007199254740992`).