# Size of integers in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

This [page](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure) says the following:

> ClojureScript currently only supports integer and floating point
>   literals that map to JavaScript primitives

Can someone tell me what that actually means for integer? Are they 64-bits (probably not, since it would take *two* JS numbers for that)? Or 32-bits? Or 53-bits (that being the maximum integer bits in a double AFAIK, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double?lq=1))?

[EDIT] The *reason* I want to know this, is that I want to write a "simulation", using a "cross-platform" language, such that the simulation gives the same results in the client (Browser(JS), Android, Web-Start, ...) and the Server (JVM). Floating points are know to cause "de-synchronisation" for simulations, because different hardware can give different results for the same calculation, with the same input. Therefore I want to use "integers" only, but if the size of integers differs between Clojure and ClojureScript, I'm still going to get "de-synchronisation" eventually (for example, when reaching [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), which is used in random number generators, which are heavily used in simulations).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Maps to JavaScript primitives."  Seems to me that that means that a ClojureScript integer is exactly the same as a JavaScript integer: it maps to the same primitive type.  Which according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin), is 2^53-1

Comment: According to this page, http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp , "JavaScript has only one type of numbers.", that being 64-bit floating point, aka double. So JS doesn't actually have "integers" as a type of "primitive", which is why it's not obvious to me I should assume "32-bits" from the statement about ClojureScript.

Comment: Point.  I don't deal with large values often enough for 32 bits to be a problem (I think its come up once in ten years).  Given that JS only has the one type, at 64 bits, then I would assume that ClojureScript also only has the one effective type as well, with the same properties and limitations, which is 2^53, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin

Comment: (Why the heck won't LaTeX formatting work for me now?)  Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to somehow verify the answer of @Draco18s, and eventually came to this code, in a ClojureScript REPL:

```
cljs.user=> (- (+ 9007199254740990 1) 1)
9007199254740990
cljs.user=> (- (+ 9007199254740991 1) 1)
9007199254740991
cljs.user=> (- (+ 9007199254740992 1) 1)
9007199254740991
```

It *looks like* "9007199254740992" is still a valid integer, but I thinks that's just because of rounding or something. So, it's really 9007199254740991 (or 2^53-1).

Comment: Because programming is magic, its always worth running an experiment to figure out if you're actually right. Kudos.