# Amazon cloudwatch not writing the logs as it is in actual file

Tags: json, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a JSON document whose number is 18 digits long. But In cloudwatch logs those numbers are rounded, so that they end with two zeros.
Actual JSON snippet:

```
{
  "prd_slnos": [
    {
      "start": 893800399235546485,
      "end": 893800399235546490
    }
  ]
}
```

Cloudwatch snippet:

```
{
  "prd_slnos": [
    {
      "start": 893800399235546400,
      "end": 893800399235546400,
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The maximum integer you can store in double without precision loss is 2^53. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double

Answer (score 1):

> **Value**
>
> The value for the metric.
>
> Type: `Double`
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_MetricDatum.html

The data type here is a [double-precision floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), which is a 64-bit number that supports a much larger *range* of possible values than a 64-bit integer, at the cost of precision.  Depending on the value, there are at most 15-17 digits of precision available.

Working this out by hand, I came up with the following value as the closest number possible number to the given input numbers, when the number is represented as a double.  I've arrived at a slightly different value than CloudWatch is displaying, presumably because I rounded away from 0 and they rounded toward 0, but you see the implication -- two different numbers both have the same nearest possible number that is representable in double-precision encoding, and this gives the appearance of the two numbers being not only equivalent when they aren't, but also "rounded off," as you've seen.     This is a limitation of double-precision encoding -- not every number can be represented.

```
# original value      # nearest number in double-precision encoding
893800399235546485 -> 893800399235546600
893800399235546490 -> 893800399235546600
```

Cloudwatch appears to be behaving as documented.