# C++ count inf when we try to find variance and mean of 2 big values 1.18973e+4932

Tags: c++

I have a vector where are 2 values 1.18973e+4932, 1.18973e+4932

```
vector<long double> v;
```

In my coursework, I need to find **mean** and **variance** of all values in the vector.

```
  long double mean() const {
     long double sum = 0;

     for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < len ; i ++)
       sum += v[i];

     return sum/len;
  }
```

Here I try to find variance

```
  long double variance() const {
     long double m = mean();
     long double sum = 0;

     for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < len ; i ++) 
       sum += (v[i] - m) * (v[i] - m);

     return sum/len;
}
```

But I am getting inf as result with 1.18973e+4932 values

Comment: It depends on what `long double` compiles to in your build environment, but I do know that `1.18973e+4932` is waaaaay bigger than the [maximum range of a 64-bit float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double), and is only barely smaller than the maximum range of an 80-bit float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going forwards with this answer *assuming* that you're using `long double` because your compiler is compiling it into 80-bit floats.

Your first problem is in your `mean()` function, where `1.18973e+4932 + 1.18973e+4932` is immediately overflowing into infinity, as the maximum value of 80-bit floats is ~1.2e+4932. `inf / 2` is still equal to `inf`, so your `mean()` function is returning `inf` as the value.

Then, in your variance function, you're calculating `(1.18973e+4932 - inf) * (1.18973e+4932 - inf)` which resolves to `-inf * -inf` which resolves to `inf`. Then, yet again, `inf / 2` equals `inf`.

As you mentioned in your own answer, dividing each member by 2 as you sum them, instead of summing and then dividing, avoids the overflow (though this solution will fail if, instead of dealing with extremely large numbers, you start dealing with extremely small numbers!)

The other solution is to borrow a multiprecision library (like [boost.multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)) and drop your values into a `quad` or larger floating point type that won't overflow when dealing with these kinds of calculations.

Comment: It works for me)) But thank you very much for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I am ashamed. that I wasn't able to solve it before...

The answer that you can divide value before the addition of numbers

mean:

```
  long double mean() const {
     long double sum = 0;

     for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < len ; i ++)
       sum += v[i]/len;

     return sum;
    }
```

variance:

it uses mean it will be 0