# Converting time_t to double and back

Tags: c++, c

I suppose to convert `time_t` value to `double` and then back: `double` to `time_t`.

In what cases I might lose data in converting?

Comment: What is the underlying type of your `time_t`?  It is unspecified per the standard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... convert `time_t` value to double and then back ...
>   In what cases I might lose data in converting?

In some cases, nothing.  `time_t` is some *real type*. C11 §7.27.1 3
Integer and real floating types are collectively called *real types*.  C11 §6.2.5 17

So if `time_t` was the same as a `double`, no loss is expected in conversion.

`time_t` is usually represented as 32 or 64 bit integer.  [Typical `double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) can encode all 53-bit unsigned values (or 54 bit signed integer values) exactly and so when `time_t` is a 32-bit integer, no conversion loss should occur.  When `time_t` is a 64-bit integer, conversion to `double` begin to incurring rounding with values outside 2<sup>53</sup> in magnitude.

The 2nd conversion back step should never occur any loss if the `double` value was from an original `time_t`, but can incur undefined behavior if an arbitrary `double` was attempted to be changed to an integer.

Less common, `time_t` could be a `float`, `long double`, `long long`, etc. and similar issues apply.