# Difference between int(r/2) and r//2 outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was making an integer to Boolean program and was dealing with some large numbers
The test case was - 15921396743627894741911

When I used

`r/2` the output was `7.960698371813948e+21`

`int(r/2)` gave me `7960698371813947736064`

and `r//2` gave me `7960698371813947370955`

Why is the value for the last two cases so vastly different. Thank you

Comment: https://0.30000000000000004.com/ -- but also there's some more subtle stuff happening -- I believe this is a duplicate target though? https://stackoverflow.com/q/53891566/812183

Comment: Interestingly, this problem is not there with Python 2.x

Comment: the values are not different check `(r/2)-int(r/2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3, `/` does "true division", which returns a float, but floats have limited precision.