# MATLAB error: Matrix is too large to return linear indices

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find all non-zeros elements in a large sparse matrix K(19683000x19683000). I used find to first return the linear indices.

```
val = K(K~=0);
inds = find(K~=0);
[j, i] = ind2sub(size(K), inds);
% [j, i] = find(K~=0);
i = full(i);
j = full(j);
```

This gave some error:

```
Error using find
Matrix is too large to return linear indices.
Use [i,j] = find(S) for sparse matrix.
Error in (line 82)
inds = find(K~=0);
Error in run (line 64)
evalin('caller', [script ';']);
```

Any idea what is happening and how I can avoid it?

Comment: I have never found that error, probably because I never used matrices so large. The error is likely related with the fact that `double` variables can exactly represent integers up to `2^53-1` only. The number of elements of your matrix does not exceed that limit, but it is near

Comment: Maybe you can sidestep the issue (up to `2^53-1`) by getting the row and column indices, and then computing the linear index from those manually: `[ii,jj] = find(K); inds = ii + (jj-1)*size(K,1)`

Comment: @LuisMendo indeed this is a solution for me. Thanks. Maybe you can put your suggestion as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Glad it worked. I rephrased a bit and added as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with that error (probably because I never used matrices so large). The error is likely related with the fact that `double` variables can [exactly represent integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1848700/2586922) up to `2^53` only. The number of elements of your matrix does not exceed that limit, but it is near.

Maybe you can sidestep the issue, up to `2^53`, by getting the row and column indices and then computing the linear index from those manually:

```
[ii,jj] = find(K);
inds = ii + (jj-1)*size(K,1);
```

If needed, you can push the limit up to `2^64` by using a `uint64` linear index instead of `double`:

```
[ii,jj] = find(K);
inds = uint64(ii) + (uint64(jj)-1)*size(K,1);
```

Comment: There's a built in function to do the conversion: sub2ind

Comment: @Philip Sure. I got into the habit of doing it manually because it's slightly faster :-)