# How does one put typeclass into a record?

Tags: haskell

While dusting off Haskell, I wanted to parse some ad-hoc data.

I found [decimal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.2.3/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Text.html#v:decimal) that can parse a number.

But I cannot put things like `Integral a` into a record easily. What is the recommended approach to put such data into a structure with named fields?

EDIT: There's a lot of answers/comments of the kind "don't" and "why would you want to do that". So, let me restate the question: given `decimal :: Integral a => Parser a`, and that I can get `a` by running the parser, how do I put that `a` into a record?

Comment: General, your data type stays unconstrained, and you put the constraints on functions that use values. That is, `data Foo a = ...` can use values of any type `a`, but `fooOp :: Integral a => Foo a -> Foo a` can only a subset of all possible `Foo a` types.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? There are two things your description might mean, and both are somewhere between "extremely niche" and "don't do this". What's the use case? What do you want to happen?

Comment: I wanted to to parse a few numbers from input lines like "some_text 1 2 15%" using Haskell and print out sums of some columns. Got stuck with type classes because I wasn't sure if the numbers were integers or floats and couldn't figure out what to do. I got impression that either type should work, just didn't know how to construct the record containing that one type.

Comment: Then this is definitely not how you want to do it. Classes shouldn't be involved at all. Maybe you want to use `Rational`. Maybe you want a  data type with constructors for each of `Integer` and `Double` and promotion rules for how to do arithmetic when the operands are mixed. But you are parsing data with a fixed format. You don't need to support whatever esoteric flavors of `Integral` might happen to be defined in your code or a library it imports.

Comment: I second what Carl wrote. If you really can not commit to a specific numeric type, make your record type be parametric over it, e.g. `data MyRecord a = { x1 :: a , x2 :: String , x3 :: [a] }`, and then write something like `myParser :: Integral a => Parser (MyRecord a)`. You'll need to add `Integral a =>` to a lot of other function. In any case, I don't think you really want a universal or existential quantification in your record type. Stick to `Integer`, or use the parametric approach I just suggested.

Comment: Thanks @chi, this actually helped me to recall the "pattern" that I completely forgot about.

Comment: Re: your "EDIT".  Actually, there's exactly one answer and half a comment telling you not to do that.  There are 2.5 comments and one answer telling you exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I can interpret your question in two different ways. Depending on which one you meant, one of these will be what you're asking for:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

data Foo = MkFoo { bar :: forall a. Integral a => a }
```

In the first one, you can only put in polymorphic things that can become any possible `Integral`, and as a result, you can use it as whatever `Integral` type you want when you take it out. This is a higher-rank type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Foo = forall a. Integral a => MkFoo { bar :: a }
```

In the second one, you can put in any `Integral` type you want, but then when you take it out, the exact type is forgotten, so you can only do things on it that the `Integral` typeclass allows, rather than anything specific to the type you put in. This is an existential type.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the "ExistentialQuantification" version loses information contained in `decimal` result, so it cannot be a correct answer. It sounds that "RankNTypes" does propagate the information fully - a caller of `decimal` can pick any type satisfying the constraint. Please help me confirm and I'll be happy to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If only there was a numeric type that could somehow store both integers *and* floating point numbers...

```
x :: [Double]
x = [10, 3.1415]
```

Well, would you look at that!

In short, unless you are batshit crazy or parsing a few billion lines of ad hoc data where floating point performance becomes a critical issue, you should just use `Double`.  The function `fromIntegral` would do a bang up job converting the result from `decimal` to a `Double`, but since you want to be able to parse both `10` and `3.1415`, you don't want to use `decimal` anyway.  Use [`double`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.2.3/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Text.html#v:double).

And before anyone says anything foolish, calculations on integral `Double` values are always exact, unless you need to store a number with absolute value greater than [2^53](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848762/7203016) = 9007199254740992.