# JSON TIME into new Date()?

Tags: javascript

This is what I received from an API.

```
{"$id":"1","currentDateTime":"2021-01-20T22:29-05:00","utcOffset":"-05:00:00","isDayLightSavingsTime":false,"dayOfTheWeek":"Wednesday","timeZoneName":"Eastern Standard Time","currentFileTime":132556553638838375,"ordinalDate":"2021-20","serviceResponse":null}`
```

It's in JSON format so I did this.

```
function setTime(data) {
let readDate = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(readDate);
let now = new Date(readDate.currentFileTime);
console.log(now);
```

}

I can't figure out how to convert it into a `new Date()`?

I assume I take the currentFileTime property of the object and I was hoping a combination of the Date methods would work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If that didn't work, try using the `currentDateTime` exactly as it is, a string, inside `var now = new Date(currentDateTime);`

Comment: that didn't work. It says invalid date. Sorry, if I wasn't clear. I want to convert it into a 24 hour clock format. So something like 12:32:30:13

Comment: What's the format of `currentFileTime`?

Comment: Yea so apparently...."The FILETIME structure is a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601."   I had no idea. Anybody who is curious http://worldclockapi.com/ is the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FILETIME` represents time as 100-nanseconds integer since January 1, 1601 ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime)). The `Date` constructor represents time as milliseconds since the epoch (January 1, 1970) ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Time_value_or_timestamp_number)).

Thus, to get a JS `Date` out of a `FILETIME`, we need to divide by 10,000 and subtract the difference between January 1, 1970 and January 1, 1601, in milliseconds. The difference is 11,644,474,854,000 ms:

```js
const windowsEpoch = new Date('January 1, 1601');
const unixEpoch = new Date('January 1, 1970');
console.log(unixEpoch - windowsEpoch);
```

Here's the code:

```js
function filetimeToDate(filetime) {
  const epochsDiff = 11644474854000;
  return new Date((filetime / 10000) - epochsDiff);
}

function setTime(data) {
  let readDate = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
  let now = filetimeToDate(readDate.currentFileTime);
  console.log(now);
}
setTime({"$id":"1","currentDateTime":"2021-01-20T22:29-05:00","utcOffset":"-05:00:00","isDayLightSavingsTime":false,"dayOfTheWeek":"Wednesday","timeZoneName":"Eastern Standard Time","currentFileTime":132556553638838375,"ordinalDate":"2021-20","serviceResponse":null});
```

**Edit:** The above numbers, and calculations, are actually inaccurate, because JS uses double-precision floating point ([that can store up to 2^53 precisely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848762/7884305)), but we're dealing with 64-bit integers. If the precision is important to you (up to seconds or milliseconds), you can use [`BigInt`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt). However, I didn't use that because the difference isn't significant and `BigInt`s: a) slow down the calculations, and b) are not portable as plain JS numbers yet.