# Python large numbers (float and integer)

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, precision, largenumber

I am trying to understand the following calculation results. `Out[1]`, `Out[2]` and `Out[3]` seem to be related to the limit on precision of floats, and `Out[4]` may be due to the fact that there is no limit on digits of `int`. Correct? I wonder if someone can explain them in more detail.

```
In [1]: 2.0**52 == 2.0**52 + 1.0
Out[1]: False

In [2]: 2.0**53 == 2.0**53 + 1.0
Out[2]: True

In [3]: 2**53 == 2**53 + 1.0
Out[3]: True

In [4]: 2**53 == 2**53 + 1
Out[4]: False
```

Comment: Yes. The answer is yes. It sounds like you have an excellent handle on it. What would you like clarified?

Comment: Python's floats are standard IEEE double-precision values, which have 53 bits of precision.  Python's integers can be as large as your memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand why this happens, we must first understand the limits of int and float.

[int & float](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) type:

> Integers have unlimited precision. Floating point numbers are usually implemented using double in C;

[`pow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) function:

> For int operands, the result has the same type as the operands (after coercion) unless the second argument is negative;

A double usually occupies 64 bits, with a 52 bit mantissa. Therefore the largest integer you can store without losing precision is 2⁵³. (Integers above this limit can be stored, but precision is lost and is rounded to another integer.) Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double) for more information.

`Out[1]`: `2.0**52` is a float, and it can also store the exact value of it, thus it returns `False`.

`Out[2]`: `2.0**53` is a float, but `2.0**53 + 1.0` is too large for it to handle, so it is rounded to the nearest power of 2 (which is `2.0**53`). Therefore, it returns `True`.

`Out[3]`: `2**53` is an int (because of how the pow function works), however `1.0` is a float, so when these 2 are added, the int gets casted to a float. Just as above, it gets rounded. That is why when the 2 are compared, it also returns `True`.

`Out[4]`: `2**53` and `1` are ints, and since they have unlimited precision, the added 1 is not rounded off, and thus returns `False`.

Comment: Actually a float can store many integers larger than `2**53`, it's just that it loses some precision.  `2**53` is the largest it can handle before the difference between representable integers is greater than 1.