# why a long numeric value changed after converting the variable from character to numeric?

Tags: r, string, duplicates, format, numeric

I concatenated some varibales to create an ID, I created two types of variables concatenated (both with same values), one in a string format and the other in a numeric format. But the result differs in the last 2 digits, it supossed to be the same, I used the same values

```
id_viv <- SD %>%          
  mutate(id_viv = 
     as.numeric(paste0(cd_a, ent, con, v_sel,
                                    n_hog, h_mud, n_ren, n_pro_viv)),
     id_viv_char = (paste0(cd_a, ent, con, v_sel,
                         n_hog, h_mud, n_ren, n_pro_viv)))
```

[image]

At first, I thought those values were exactly the same and they were just different in a visual perspective. So I tried to compared both with the duplicated function but they were actually different...

first result

```
table(duplicated(id_viv$id_viv))
```

output:

```
FALSE   TRUE 
403296    356
```

second result

```
table(duplicated(id_viv$id_viv_char))
```

output:

```
 FALSE   TRUE 
 403644      8
```

Someone knows why this happen?

P.S: This also happens in STATA

Comment: Could you provide `str`? And have a look here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal>

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double