# How to filter and print only integers within a range of square roots in Swift arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to print only the sqrt that are in the int form (1,2,3,4,5) only numbers who are sqrt
but I don't have the right code to do that.Thank you in advance

I tried to use if statement with I == int print  but no didn't succeed

I want the program to skip doubles and print only int

Comment: Why the down-vote? For somebody very new to programming, data types can be confusing, and even expressing what you are trying to do can be hard. Let's give new posters some slack!

Comment: @DuncanC That was exactly my thinking. It seems like a very reasonable question, although I suspect people are responding negatively because it doesn't include the failing code example or any error details. The formatting is also pretty wonky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [`sqrt()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1557357-sqrt?language=objc), [`Double.squareRoot()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/squareroot()), etc., the resulting value's *type* will always consistently be a `Double`, regardless of whether it's a whole number or not.

Checking if an `Int` (e.g. `result is Int`) will always be `false`, and the compiler will tell you that:

```
import Foundation

print(sqrt(4) is Int) // warning: cast from 'Double' to unrelated type 'Int' always fails
```

What you need to do is check if the result you you get is a whole number:

```
import Foundation

print(sqrt(4).remainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0) // true
```

Comment: Will taking the square root of perfect squares return exact values, or will there be rounding error such that sqrt(16) is not exactly 4?

Comment: I just tried it an it worked. (voted)

Comment: @DuncanC It'll start failing at some point, but it's true all the way up to at least 2^53, (which is the [last consecutive whole number that's precisely representable with a `Double`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848762/3141234), which is `Double(sign: .plus, exponent: Double.significandBitCount + 1, significand: 1)`), equal to `9,007,199,254,740,992`)

Comment: I think 2^53 is pretty good. It would take... a while to iterate that many values.