# Is it safe to use fmax for integer types in C?

Tags: c, standards

According to [the standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmax), `fmax` (the function, not macro) takes two `double`s and returns a `double`. Is it safe to pass integers to the function?

One consideration I’m aware of is the size of the types. `long long` fits in `double`, but I don’t know if it’s always the case.

I don’t know any other considerations involved in type conversions.

`fmax` works fine but I want to make sure if my understanding of it is valid.

Comment: Why do you want to use `fmax` for integer values? Especially since creating your own function or macro is so easy?

Comment: The biggest integer that double can exactly represent is [9007199254740992](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double). So it will work fine for `int`, may not give exact results for the whole range of `long long`.

Comment: #define MAX(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b)) will work for all integer types, float and doubles.

Comment: You use the word "safe" at one point and then ask if it's "valid" in another.  These are completely different concepts.

Comment: @Fredrik Unless arguments are expressions with side-effects.

Comment: @teapot418, while you're right that representation can be inexact for larger values, the exact limit is of course not specified by C (it's implementation-defined, and depends on the particular floating-point representation used).

Comment: Regardless of whether this is safe or not, it's generally a bad idea to do unnecessary conversions between integer and floating point types. It is slower and you risk having inaccurate results due to conversion losses. In your case, unless you absolutely want to have final result in `double`, then just do comparison with integer type.

Answer (score 4):

You use the word "safe" at one point and then ask if it's "valid" in another.  These are completely different concepts.  What is valid may not be safe.

It is NOT "safe" to pass arbitrary long long and expect a good mathematical result from `fmax`.

Consider the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    long long a = 9223372036854775807;
    long long b = 9223372036854775806;

    double result = fmax((double)a, (double)b);

    printf("Result of fmax: %f\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

which gives me

```
Result of fmax: 9223372036854775808.000000
```

Comment: Additionally, converting the result back to `long long` has undefined behavior in this case.  using `fmaxl` with type `long double` does not fix the problem as `long double` may be implemented as equivalent to `double`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to use fmax for integer types in C?

It is safe. The C programming language has [*implicit* conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion), they happen automatically. The argument will be *converted* to double, and then the function will be called.

The only dangerous territory is specifically the conversion, not the function itself. The function receives a double, always. The rules, from https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion, are :

> A value of any integer type can be implicitly converted to any real floating type.
>
> - if the value can be represented exactly by the target type, it is unchanged
> - if the value can be represented, but cannot be represented exactly, the result is an implementation-defined choice of either the nearest higher or nearest lower value, although if IEEE arithmetic is supported, rounding is to nearest. It is unspecified whether FE_INEXACT is raised in this case.
> - if the value cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined, although if IEEE arithmetic is supported, FE_INVALID is raised and the result value is unspecified.

The last case, "if the value cannot be represented", is the "unsafe" part. When the integer is big (or small) "enough" that it is greater than the biggest (or smallest) double, then it is unsafe. This rule is for any integer to double conversions in any contexts.

> long long fits in double, but I don’t know if it’s **always** the case.

It is hard to traverse *all* implementations, including future ones, to find a case where the rule is broken. The C standard says that `DBL_MAX` has to be **at least** `1E+37` and `LLONG_MAX` has to be **at least** `+9223372036854775807`. It is perfectly allowed for an implementation to exists with `LLONG_MAX` greater than `1E+37` and `DBL_MAX` equal to `1E+37`. Or any other combination, where it would be unsafe.

However, nowadays, the abundant implementations have `long long` in a twos-complement integer with width of 64-bits and `double` in the IEEE754 double-precision floating-point format `float64`. In such implementations, with LLONG_MAX being ~9.2e+18 and DBL_MAX holding whooping ~1.7E+308, you are safe.

So, unless you are programming for a really odd machine, where you will know that you are programming for such, you are safe. You might be interested in https://begriffs.com/posts/2018-11-15-c-portability.html . Joke: on a [DeathStation 9000](http://wikibin.org/articles/deathstation-9000.html) converting too big integer to a double will end the life as we know it.

Comment: *"The last case, "if the value cannot be represented", is the "unsafe" part."* Depending on the context the middle case *"if the value can be represented, but cannot be represented exactly"* can also be "unsafe" part.

Comment: hi @user694733 I think we miss in the definition of "unsafe". For me, "unsafe" straight up means undefined behavior, nothing more and nothing _less_. Implementation defined behavior, specifically on IEEE, is _exactly defined_ and if the integer value cannot be represented exactly as floating-point, doesn't matter, because the result will be computed _exactly_ to the rules of IEEE. I.e. "safeness", for me, is the ability to predict the behavior. In case integer cannot be represented exactly as floating point, the conversion is still "safe" - can be exactly predicted, especially on IEEE.