Why are INumber<T>.CreateX(int n) so slow compared to implicit conversion for floats and doubles?
I'm working on a Maths library, and I'd like to be able to convert it to use the new INumber<T> interfaces in System.Numerics. The methods in here are often on hot paths and so would be good if they can be as fast as possible, while also being pleasant to work with. I've been benchmarking them as I go, and noticed something that seems a little odd.
There's a few cases where we divide an array value by its index, due to using System.Numerics, this cannot be done via an implicit conversion like you would when the type is defined, the recommended method seems to be to use INumber<T>.Create{Checked|Saturating|Truncating}(int n)
The benchmark methods I'm running are fairly simple, like so:
public static double[] DivideByImplicit(double[] values)
{
    double[] result = new double[values.Length];
    for (int i = 1; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = values[i] / i;
    }

    return result;
}

// Overloads for other types (int, long, float, decimal)
// ...


public static T[] DivideByChecked<T>(T[] values) where T : INumber<T>
{
    T[] result = new T[values.Length];
    for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = values[i] / T.CreateChecked(i);
    }

    return result;
}

// Same again but for Saturating/Truncating
// ...

For int, long and decimal, the results are within a few percentage points at most, but when it comes to float and double there's a much larger performance hit, ~25% for double but up to a full 100% increase in time for float:



Method
Categories
Count
Mean
Error
StdDev
Ratio
RatioSD




DivideByImplicitDecimal
decimal
1000
29,292.733 ns
146.0540 ns
136.6190 ns
1.00
0.00


DivideByCheckedDecimal
decimal
1000
28,884.550 ns
82.0562 ns
76.7554 ns
0.99
0.00


DivideBySaturatingDecimal
decimal
1000
29,948.023 ns
61.6380 ns
54.6404 ns
1.02
0.01


DivideByTruncatingDecimal
decimal
1000
30,367.067 ns
67.0287 ns
62.6987 ns
1.04
0.01












DivideByImplicitDouble
double
1000
1,067.421 ns
20.5178 ns
24.4250 ns
1.00
0.00


DivideByCheckedDouble
double
1000
1,342.562 ns
17.7660 ns
14.8354 ns
1.25
0.03


DivideBySaturatingDouble
double
1000
1,343.400 ns
16.4938 ns
13.7731 ns
1.25
0.04


DivideByTruncatingDouble
double
1000
1,394.057 ns
27.2936 ns
44.0740 ns
1.31
0.04












DivideByImplicitFloat
float
1000
636.576 ns
4.9312 ns
4.6127 ns
1.00
0.00


DivideByCheckedFloat
float
1000
1,282.109 ns
13.9466 ns
12.3633 ns
2.01
0.02


DivideBySaturatingFloat
float
1000
1,288.927 ns
10.4365 ns
8.7149 ns
2.03
0.02


DivideByTruncatingFloat
float
1000
1,291.335 ns
20.6446 ns
17.2392 ns
2.03
0.04












DivideByImplicitInt
int
1000
1,210.849 ns
13.0819 ns
12.2368 ns
1.00
0.00


DivideByCheckedInt
int
1000
1,202.773 ns
7.3879 ns
6.5492 ns
0.99
0.01


DivideBySaturatingInt
int
1000
1,201.430 ns
8.0413 ns
6.7149 ns
0.99
0.01


DivideByTruncatingInt
int
1000
1,199.158 ns
9.0592 ns
7.0728 ns
0.99
0.01












DivideByImplicitLong
long
1000
1,712.002 ns
19.3905 ns
17.1891 ns
1.00
0.00


DivideByCheckedLong
long
1000
1,716.886 ns
17.9844 ns
16.8226 ns
1.00
0.01


DivideBySaturatingLong
long
1000
1,712.213 ns
31.2334 ns
29.2157 ns
1.00
0.02


DivideByTruncatingLong
long
1000
1,771.120 ns
34.2546 ns
40.7777 ns
1.03
0.03



Why is the impact so much higher when converting to a float/double than it is to any other numeric type? Not shown for brevity, but I also ran benchmarks for arrays of size 1, 100 and 1_000_000, and the slowdown wasn't visible on 1 or 100, but was similar on 1_000_000.

Maybe better to show comparison between DivideByImplicit and DivideByChecked for float and double? Also you can analyse what is compiled using sharplab.io

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Ah sorry that's my bad for bad naming, I've updated the benchmark method results to show the actual method being called.

My guess is: conversion from int to int/long is pretty much free. Conversion from int to float/double is not. JIT compiler can of course do some shenanigans if it knows concrete types. With generics it is less likely to be properly optimized, even if technically possible. For example it is not clear that it will inline the Create* calls (which would be necessary). The same applies to conversion from int to decimal. However decimals are just slow by nature, so I think that the overhead is dominated by other factors. Either way, I don't think you will get a definite answer here.

Because there is boxing involved? T.CreateChecked(value) does a type check and a cast to object. See how double does it: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Double.cs,4aa7a7c31c08dfe4

@freakish yeah that's kinda what I was expecting, it was mainly the fact that the slowdown is so different between the various types that was stumping me.
Having a look at the JIT ASM in Sharplab, I can see that the slowdowns are roughly correlated with the "length" of ASM instructions produced. I guess my remaining question is why/if there are limitations stopping the compiler/dotnet team from making it more optimal

@JBrown521 well, this is purely speculative. But remember that JITting itself is not free. And therefore writing a JIT requires keeping a balance: you want to optimize things as much as possible, but not more. Because generally the process of optimization itself takes time, and high level optimizations typically take lots of time. While on the other hand most of the code does not require those costly optimizations (which are not free, even when they do nothing ultimately). So perhaps that's where the boundary lies? Again: that's my guess, but only them devs would know that.

@Dennis_E there is always boxing involved (for long as well).

can't repro more than 10% deviation for float. Must be my old laptop.

@Dennis_E boxing can of course be optimized away by JIT.

CreateChecked can be slow if the type you want is not the one you are passing in. You could make the loop use another looping variable which is typed as T and use that for your division.
public static T[] DivideByChecked<T>(T[] values) where T : INumber<T>
{
    T[] result = new T[values.Length];
    var tI = T.MultiplicativeIdentity;
    for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = values[i] / tI;
        tI++;
    }

    return result;
}


Would incrementing a double reduce accuracy?

Not whole numbers, no, untl you get to 2^53, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848762/14868997 Which I need not tell you is a stupid big number, and much larger than the maximum array length
